# C99 stdint.h header and MS Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, c99

To my amazement I just discovered that the C99 stdint.h is missing from MS Visual Studio 2003 upwards.  I'm sure they have their reasons, but does anyone know where I can download a copy?  Without this header I have no definitions for useful types such as uint32_t, etc.

Comment: As an update to this: MSVC 2010 now includes `stdint.h`

Comment: Going by this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-preview.aspx, *VS 2015 Preview fully supports the C99 Standard Library (with the only omissions being tgmath.h, which requires C compiler magic and is not relevant to C++ which has overloading, and CX_LIMITED_RANGE/FP_CONTRACT which also require compiler support).*

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Turns out you can download a MS version of this header from:

https://github.com/mattn/gntp-send/blob/master/include/msinttypes/stdint.h

A portable one can be found here:

http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/pstdint.h

Thanks to the [Software Rambling](http://stephendoyle.blogspot.com/2008/03/c-tr1-stdinth-still-missing-from-visual.html)s blog.

*NB:* The Public Domain version of the header, mentioned by [Michael Burr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12711/michael-burr) in a comment, can be find as an archived copy [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20101104120614/http://snipplr.com/view/18199/stdinth/). An updated version can be found in [the Android source tree for libusb_aah](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libusb_aah/+/master/msvc/stdint.h).

Comment: A public domain (not an MIT/BSD license - you don't even need to keep a copyright attribution around) stdint.h for MSVC (a slightly modified version from MinGW): http://snipplr.com/view/18199/stdinth/

Comment: The first link 404s

Comment: Modified the original answer but: https://github.com/mattn/gntp-send/blob/master/include/msinttypes/stdint.h the svn link is dead

Answer (score 50):

Just define them yourself.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER

typedef __int32 int32_t;
typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;
typedef __int64 int64_t;
typedef unsigned __int64 uint64_t;

#else
#include <stdint.h>
#endif
```

Comment: Am I missing something or shouldn't it be typedef unsigned __int64 uint64_t; ?

Comment: And to use literal uint64_t values it is useful to `#define U64(u) (u##ui64)` on Windows and to `#define U64(u) (u##ULL)` otherwise.

Answer (score 49):

Update: **Visual Studio 2010** and **Visual C++ 2010 Express** both have `stdint.h`. It can be found in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include`

Comment: As well as <cstdint> for C++ users who like it in `std::`.

Answer (score 25):

Visual Studio 2003 - 2008 (Visual C++ 7.1 - 9) don't claim to be C99 compatible.  (Thanks to rdentato for his comment.)

Answer (score 11):

Boost contains cstdint.hpp header file with the types you are looking for: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/boost/cstdint.hpp

Comment: boost is C++, the question is on C99

Comment: It is not clear - he is asking about a C99 header in Visual Studio, without specifying which language he is using. In any case it can't be C99 because Microsoft does not support it.

Comment: OP wants a copy of `<stdint.h>`, not a Boost header.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft do not support C99 and haven't announced any plans to. I believe they intend to track C++ standards but consider C as effectively obsolete except as a subset of C++.

New projects in Visual Studio 2003 and later have the "Compile as C++ Code (/TP)" option set by default, so any .c files will be compiled as C++.

Answer (score 4):

Another portable solution:

POSH: The Portable Open Source Harness

"POSH is a simple, portable, easy-to-use, easy-to-integrate, flexible, open source "harness" designed to make writing cross-platform libraries and applications significantly less tedious to create and port."

http://poshlib.hookatooka.com/poshlib/trac.cgi

as described and used in the book:
Write portable code: an introduction to developing software for multiple platforms
By Brian Hook
http://books.google.ca/books?id=4VOKcEAPPO0C

-Jason

Comment: From Poshlib Wikipedia article, the link authorization is:username: guest, password: guest123

Comment: Grand total of 3 commits, last one dated September 2006