# Converting a pointer into an integer

Tags: c++, gcc, casting, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am trying to adapt an existing code to a 64 bit machine. The main problem is that in one function, the previous coder uses a void* argument that is converted into suitable type in the function itself. A short example:

```
void function(MESSAGE_ID id, void* param)
{
    if(id == FOO) {
        int real_param = (int)param;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Of course, on a 64 bit machine, I get the error:

```
error: cast from 'void*' to 'int' loses precision
```

I would like to correct this so that it still works on a 32 bit machine and as cleanly as possible. Any idea ?

Comment: I know this is digging up an old post, but it seems like the accepted answer is not quite correct. A concrete example of `size_t` not working is i386 segmented memory. Though a 32-bit machine, `sizeof` returns `2` for `size_t`. [Alex answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26586211/608639) appears correct. Alex's answer and `uintptr_t` works just about everywhere and its now standard. It provides a C++11 treatment, and it even gives the C++03 header guards.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`.

To ensure it is defined in a portable way, you can use code like this:

```
#if defined(__BORLANDC__)
    typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
    typedef __int64 int64_t;
    typedef unsigned long uintptr_t;
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
    typedef __int64 int64_t;
#else
    #include <stdint.h>
#endif
```

Just place that in some .h file and include wherever you need it.

Alternatively, you can download Microsoft’s version of the `stdint.h` file from [here](http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stdint.h">http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stdint.h) or use a portable one from [here](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/pstdint.h">http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/pstdint.h).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126279/c99-stdinth-header-and-ms-visual-studio for info on how to get a stdint.h that works with MSVC (and possibly Borland).

Comment: Both links broken!

Comment: This answer is related to C but the language is tagged **C++** so it not the answer what i was looking for.

Comment: @HaSeeBMiR An appropriate fix is to switch to `<cstdint>`, or to download the appropriate `cstdint` if you download a `stdint.h`.

Comment: @JustinTime But it would still remain c++ , adding **<cstdint>** or any c-header file doesnt make language c. this is an extension is compilers to support old **.h** legacy header files in modern c++ compilers thats why c++ had to support this and add all **.h** C-Header files as **<c-header-file>** . still i would prefer people answer according to tags related to what OP asked.

Comment: @HaSeeBMiR The only reason the answer is related to C instead of C++ is that it uses a C header instead of the equivalent C++ header.  The C preprocessor is a part of C++, and `cstdint` is a part of the C++ standard, as are all of the type names defined there.  It is indeed appropriate for the specified tags.  ...I do disagree with defining the types manually, but it may be necessary when working with compilers that don't do so.

Comment: This answer is incredibly outdated. These days, just `#include <cstdint>`.

Answer (score 142):

I'd say this is the modern C++ way:

```
#include <cstdint>
void *p;
auto i = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(p);
```

**EDIT**:

### The correct type to the the Integer

So the right way to store a pointer as an integer is to use the `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t` types. (See also in cppreference [integer types for C99](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer)).

These types are defined in `<stdint.h>` for C99 and in the namespace `std` for C++11 in `<cstdint>` (see [integer types for C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)).

**C++11 (and onwards) Version**

```
#include <cstdint>
std::uintptr_t i;
```

**C++03 Version**

```
extern "C" {
#include <stdint.h>
}

uintptr_t i;
```

**C99 Version**

```
#include <stdint.h>
uintptr_t i;
```

### The correct casting operator

In C there is only one cast and using the C cast in C++ is frowned upon (so don't use it in C++). In C++ there are different types of casts, but `reinterpret_cast` is the correct cast for this conversion (see also [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)).

**C++11 Version**

```
auto i = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(p);
```

**C++03 Version**

```
uintptr_t i = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(p);
```

**C Version**

```
uintptr_t i = (uintptr_t)p; // C Version
```

### Related Questions

- [What is uintptr_t data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845482/what-is-uintptr-t-data-type)

Comment: the only answer which properly mentions reinterpret_cast

Comment: If you meant to include <cstdint>, you probably also want to use std::uintptr_t instead.

Comment: Awesome... The cast is what I was looking for. If we are told to use `uintptr_t` instead of `size_t`, then why does it require `reinterpret_cast`? It seems like a simple `static_cast` should do since the standard specifically provides the compatible data types...

Comment: @jww read: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast my understanding here is that `static_cast` might convert the type or if it's a pointer might do pointer adjustments if the type needs it. `reinterpret_cast` is really just changing the type of the underlying memory pattern (no mutations). to clarify: `static_cast` does behave identical here.

Comment: this should be marked as selected answer instead, as it provides all the details how to cast in **C and C++**.

Comment: So there are people who write C++ who have the `*` by the variable name! Lovely.  I cringe every time I see code like `long* j;` and even worse when it's in C. As for C casts in C++ (for pointers) I believe that more recent versions of GCC complain about it or maybe even restrict it? Or maybe it was the standard? Otherwise it's my imagination - which is entirely possible I suppose.

Comment: @Pryftan It's fine to have a personal preference, but it's quite strange to "cringe" at something that the C++ language is moving towards. Modern C++ (11 onward) has a clear preference for type-aligned qualifiers. For example, you simply cannot align `*`, `&`, or `&&` with the name of a  variadic packs since it comes before the `...`. Plus, of course, everything is increasingly left-ot-right with `auto`: `int *get_ptr()` becomes `auto get_ptr() -> int*`, `int *p = &q` becomes `auto p = &q`, etc.

Answer (score 42):

'size_t' and 'ptrdiff_t' are required to match your architecture (whatever it is).  Therefore, I think rather than using 'int', you should be able to use 'size_t', which on a 64 bit system should be a 64 bit type.

This discussion [unsigned int vs size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131803/unsigned-int-vs-sizet) goes into a bit more detail.

Comment: While size_t is usually large enough to hold a pointer, it's not necessarily the case.  It would be better to locate a stdint.h header  (if your compiler doesn't already have one) and use uintptr_t.

Comment: Unfortunately the only constraint on `size_t` is that it must hold the result of any `sizeof()`. This doesn't necessarily make it 64 bits on x64. [see also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1089204/762488)

Comment: ``size_t`` *can* safely store the value of a non-member pointer.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t.

Comment: @AndyJost No it cannot. Even your own link confirms that.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY: "On many platforms (an exception is systems with segmented addressing) std::size_t can safely store the value of any non-member pointer, in which case it is synonymous with std::uintptr_t." - whatever are you talking about?

Comment: `size_t` is a type that can hold any **array index**, not pointer. It generally works but there’s exception. See also: [`size_t` vs `uintptr_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464174/size-t-vs-uintptr-t)

Answer (score 17):

Use `uintptr_t` as your integer type.

Answer (score 9):

Several answers have pointed at `uintptr_t` and `#include <stdint.h>` as 'the' solution.  That is, I suggest, part of the answer, but not the whole answer.  You also need to look at where the function is called with the message ID of FOO.

Consider this code and compilation:

```
$ cat kk.c
#include <stdio.h>
static void function(int n, void *p)
{
    unsigned long z = *(unsigned long *)p;
    printf("%d - %lu\n", n, z);
}

int main(void)
{
    function(1, 2);
    return(0);
}
$ rmk kk
        gcc -m64 -g -O -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith \
            -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes \
            -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE kk.c -o kk 
kk.c: In function 'main':
kk.c:10: warning: passing argument 2 of 'func' makes pointer from integer without a cast
$
```

You will observe that there is a problem at the calling location (in `main()`) — converting an integer to a pointer without a cast.  You are going to need to analyze your `function()` in all its usages to see how values are passed to it.  The code inside my `function()` would work if the calls were written:

```
unsigned long i = 0x2341;
function(1, &i);
```

Since yours are probably written differently, you need to review the points where the function is called to ensure that it makes sense to use the value as shown.  Don't forget, you may be finding a latent bug.

Also, if you are going to format the value of the `void *` parameter (as converted), look carefully at the `<inttypes.h>` header (instead of `stdint.h` — `inttypes.h` provides the services of `stdint.h`, which is unusual, but the C99 standard says *[t]he header `<inttypes.h>` includes the header `<stdint.h>` and extends it with
additional facilities provided by hosted implementations*) and use the PRIxxx macros in your format strings.

Also, my comments are strictly applicable to C rather than C++, but your code is in the subset of C++ that is portable between C and C++.  The chances are fair to good that my comments apply.

Comment: I think you missed the point on my question. The code is storing the value of an integer in a pointer. And that part of the code is doing the opposite (e.g. extracting the value of the integer that was written *as* a pointer).

Comment: @PierreBdR Nevertheless he makes a very valid point. It's not always so simple as to look at code (including when compilers warn about it) that uses a signed int but is used for a size and think it okay to change it to unsigned. Unfortunately it's not always that simple. You have to look at each case explicitly unless you want to cause potential bugs - and subtle bugs at that.

Answer (score 4):

1. `#include <stdint.h>`
2. Use `uintptr_t` standard type defined in the included standard header file.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this question while studying the source code of [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/).

In the [sqliteInt.h](https://github.com/mackyle/sqlite/blob/master/src/sqliteInt.h#L207), there is a paragraph of code defined a macro convert between integer and pointer. The author made a very good statement first pointing out it should be a compiler dependent problem and then implemented the solution to account for most of the popular compilers out there.

```
#if defined(__PTRDIFF_TYPE__)  /* This case should work for GCC */
# define SQLITE_INT_TO_PTR(X)  ((void*)(__PTRDIFF_TYPE__)(X))
# define SQLITE_PTR_TO_INT(X)  ((int)(__PTRDIFF_TYPE__)(X))
#elif !defined(__GNUC__)       /* Works for compilers other than LLVM */
# define SQLITE_INT_TO_PTR(X)  ((void*)&((char*)0)[X])
# define SQLITE_PTR_TO_INT(X)  ((int)(((char*)X)-(char*)0))
#elif defined(HAVE_STDINT_H)   /* Use this case if we have ANSI headers */
# define SQLITE_INT_TO_PTR(X)  ((void*)(intptr_t)(X))
# define SQLITE_PTR_TO_INT(X)  ((int)(intptr_t)(X))
#else                          /* Generates a warning - but it always works     */
# define SQLITE_INT_TO_PTR(X)  ((void*)(X))
# define SQLITE_PTR_TO_INT(X)  ((int)(X))
#endif
```

And here is a quote of the comment for more details:

```
/*
** The following macros are used to cast pointers to integers and
** integers to pointers.  The way you do this varies from one compiler
** to the next, so we have developed the following set of #if statements
** to generate appropriate macros for a wide range of compilers.
**
** The correct "ANSI" way to do this is to use the intptr_t type.
** Unfortunately, that typedef is not available on all compilers, or
** if it is available, it requires an #include of specific headers
** that vary from one machine to the next.
**
** Ticket #3860:  The llvm-gcc-4.2 compiler from Apple chokes on
** the ((void*)&((char*)0)[X]) construct.  But MSVC chokes on ((void*)(X)).
** So we have to define the macros in different ways depending on the
** compiler.
*/
```

Credit goes to the committers.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing to do is to avoid converting from pointer type to non-pointer types.
However, this is clearly not possible in your case.

As everyone said, the uintptr_t is what you should use.

This [link](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/64bitPorting/MakingCode64-BitClean/chapter_4_section_4.html) has good info about converting to 64-bit code.

There is also a good discussion of this on [comp.std.c](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c/browse_thread/thread/6bf9aa8c9e7bc523)

Answer (score 0):

I think the "meaning" of void* in this case is a generic handle.
It is not a pointer to a value, it is the value itself.
(This just happens to be how void* is used by C and C++ programmers.)

If it is holding an integer value, it had better be within integer range!

Here is easy rendering to integer:

```
int x = (char*)p - (char*)0;
```

It should only give a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Since `uintptr_t` is [not guaranteed to be there in C++/C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1846648/2436175), if this is a one way conversion you can consider `uintmax_t`, always defined in [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint).

```
auto real_param = reinterpret_cast<uintmax_t>(param);
```

To play safe, one could add anywhere in the code an assertion:

```
static_assert(sizeof (uintmax_t) >= sizeof (void *) ,
              "No suitable integer type for conversion from pointer type");
```

Comment: If you do not have uintptr_t, then uintmax_t is not an answer either: there is no garanty you can store the value of a pointer in it! There might be no integer type that does that.

Answer (score 0):

With C++11, For what it's worth, suppose you don't have any headers, then define:

```cpp
template<bool B, class T, class F> struct cond { typedef T type; };
template<class T, class F> struct cond<false, T, F> { typedef F type;};
static constexpr unsigned int PS = sizeof (void *);

using uintptr_type = typename cond<
   PS==sizeof(unsigned short), unsigned short ,
      typename cond<
          PS==sizeof(unsigned int), unsigned int,
              typename cond<
                  PS==sizeof(unsigned long), unsigned long, unsigned long long>::type>::type>::type;
```

After that you can do the following:

```cpp
static uintptr_type ptr_to_int(const void *pointer) { 
    return reinterpret_cast<uintptr_type>(pointer); 
}
static void *int_to_ptr(uintptr_type integer) { 
    return reinterpret_cast<void *>(integer); 
}
```