# Where do I find the definition of size_t, and what is it used for?

Tags: c++, c, variables, size-t

I see variables defined with this type but I don't know where it comes from, nor what is its purpose. Why not use int or unsigned int? (What about other "similar" types? Void_t, etc).

Comment: Exact Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502856/whats-the-difference-between-sizet-and-int-in-c

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089176/is-sizet-always-unsigned/1089204#1089204

Comment: In minimalistic programs where a `size_t` definition was not loaded "by chance" but I still need in some context (for example to access `std::vector<double>`), the I use *that* context to extract the correct type. For example `typedef std::vector<double>::size_type size_t`.

Comment: The OP specifically asked ***Where do I find the definition of size_t?*** I landed here searching for the same thing. The cited dup does not discuss where to find the declaration.

Comment: This question is obviously not the same question as the one linked.  *"Where do I find something"* is not the same thing as *"What is the difference between"* (even if the answer to one provides the answer to the other).  My Google search for 'c++ where is size_t definition' took me straight here, and I would have missed the other question, because it's *different*.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdlib.h)

> The `stdlib.h` and `stddef.h` header files define a datatype called `size_t`[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdlib.h) which is used to represent the size of an object. Library functions that take sizes expect them to be of type `size_t`, and the sizeof operator evaluates to `size_t`.
>
> The actual type of `size_t` is platform-dependent; a common mistake is to assume `size_t` is the same as unsigned int, which can lead to programming errors,[2](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf#page=266) particularly as 64-bit architectures become more prevalent.

From [C99 7.17.1/2](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf#page=266)

> The following types and macros are defined in the standard header `stddef.h`
>
> <snip>
>
> `size_t`
>
> which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator

Comment: For example, on Win64, `int` and `unsigned int` types are 32 bits, while size_t is 64 bits.

Comment: Please refer to ISO C(99) standard (from which the C++ standard includes) sections 7.17 and 7.18.3

Comment: @LokiAstari why don't you just edit the answer since you're know where it is written in the standard?

Comment: So where is the C++ answer ?

Comment: @Lothar I think the only difference is that size_t may be a keyword, and otherwise has the same meaning.

Answer (score 45):

According to [size_t description on en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) `size_t` is defined in the following headers :

```
std::size_t

...    

Defined in header <cstddef>         
Defined in header <cstdio>      
Defined in header <cstring>         
Defined in header <ctime>       
Defined in header <cwchar>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, this answer should be upvoted.

Comment: `std::size_t` is defined in the header `<cstddef>` per the ISO C++ standard, it is used in the other listed headers.

Answer (score 29):

`size_t` is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator (ISO C99 Section 7.17.)

The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. The value of the result is implementation-deﬁned, and its type (an unsigned integer type) is `size_t` (ISO C99 Section 6.5.3.4.)

IEEE Std 1003.1-2017 (POSIX.1) specifies that `size_t` be defined in the header `sys/types.h`, whereas ISO C specifies the header `stddef.h`. In ISO C++, the type `std::size_t` is deﬁned in the standard header `cstddef`.

Comment: The best answer as it quotes the standard.

Comment: @Martin - true enough, but I think that the 'why isn't unsigned int used' part of the question is as interesting (or more) as the 'what is size_t' part, and you won't find that in the standard.

Comment: Yeah, except there is no 'Section *17.17*' :p. It's rare, no one said a word about Void_t

Comment: I accept this answer as it responds directly the question, but it would be great if it's complimented with Michael's answer.

Comment: Pity your answer doesn't tell me what header file to include.

Answer (score 6):

Practically speaking `size_t` represents the number of bytes you can address. On most modern architectures for the last 10-15 years that has been 32 bits which has also been the size of a unsigned int. However we are moving to 64bit addressing while the `uint` will most likely stay at 32bits (it's size is not guaranteed in the c++ standard). To make your code that depends on the memory size portable across architectures you should use a `size_t`. For example things like array sizes should always use `size_t`'s. If you look at the standard containers the `::size()` always returns a `size_t`.

Also note, visual studio has a compile option that can check for these types of errors called "Detect 64-bit Portability Issues".

Answer (score 2):

This way you always know what the size is, because a specific type is dedicated to sizes. The very own question shows that it can be an issue: is it an `int` or an `unsigned int`? Also, what is the magnitude (`short`, `int`, `long`, etc.)?

Because there is a specific type assigned, you don't have to worry about the length or the signed-ness.

The actual definition can be found in the [C++ Reference Library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/size_t/), which says:

> Type: `size_t` (Unsigned integral type)
>
> Header: `<cstring>`
>
> `size_t` corresponds to the integral data type returned by the language operator `sizeof` and is defined in the `<cstring>` header file (among others) as an unsigned integral type.
>
> In `<cstring>`, it is used as the type of the parameter `num` in the functions `memchr`, `memcmp`, `memcpy`, `memmove`, `memset`, `strncat`, `strncmp`, `strncpy` and `strxfrm`, which in all cases it is used to specify the maximum number of bytes or characters the function has to affect.
>
> It is also used as the return type for `strcspn`, `strlen`, `strspn` and `strxfrm` to return sizes and lengths.

Answer (score 2):

size_t should be defined in your standard library's headers.  In my experience, it usually is simply a typedef to unsigned int.  The point, though, is that it doesn't have to be.
Types like size_t allow the standard library vendor the freedom to change its underlying data types if appropriate for the platform.  If you assume size_t is always unsigned int (via casting, etc), you could run into problems in the future if your vendor changes size_t to be e.g. a 64-bit type.  It is dangerous to assume anything about this or any other library type for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `void_t` except as a result of a Google search (it's used in [a `vmalloc` library by Kiem-Phong Vo at AT&T Research](http://www.research.att.com/~gsf/man/man3/vmalloc.html) - I'm sure it's used in other libraries as well).

The various xxx_t typedefs are used to abstract a type from a particular definite implementation, since the concrete types used for certain things might differ from one platform to another.  For example:

- size_t abstracts the type used to hold the size of objects because on some systems this will be a 32-bit value, on others it might be 16-bit or 64-bit.
- `Void_t` abstracts the type of pointer returned by the `vmalloc` library routines because it was written to work on systems that pre-date ANSI/ISO C where the `void` keyword might not exist.  At least that's what I'd guess.
- `wchar_t` abstracts the type used for wide characters since on some systems it will be a 16 bit type, on others it will be a 32 bit type.

So if you write your wide character handling code to use the `wchar_t` type instead of, say `unsigned short`, that code will presumably be more portable to various platforms.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, partly. As I said in a comment in fpmurphy's answer, it would be great that it can be complemented with this answer (If you don't mind maybe you can edit it) :)

Answer (score 1):

In minimalistic programs where a `size_t` definition was not loaded "by chance" in some include but I still need it in some context (for example to access `std::vector<double>`), then I use *that* context to extract the correct type. For example `typedef std::vector<double>::size_type size_t`.

(Surround with `namespace {...}` if necessary to make the scope limited.)

Answer (score 1):

As for "Why not use int or unsigned int?", simply because it's semantically more meaningful not to. There's the practical reason that it can be, say, `typedef`d as an `int` and then upgraded to a `long` later, without anyone having to change their code, of course, but more fundamentally than that a type is supposed to be meaningful. To vastly simplify, a variable of type `size_t` is suitable for, and used for, containing the sizes of things, just like `time_t` is suitable for containing time values. How these are actually implemented should quite properly be the implementation's job. Compared to just calling everything `int`, using meaningful typenames like this helps clarify the meaning and intent of your program, just like any rich set of types does.