# Saving a size_t in a raw mem block and getting it back

Tags: c, memory, kernel, kernel-module

I'm saving a `size_t` type of data in a raw memory block in kernel land, then I send the entire memory block to user land and I try to get that `size_t` value back.

The type isn't guarantied to be equal-sized on both kernel and user land, so I'm wondering what's the best way to save the value and then restore it.

Edit:

Or, maybe just save another type of data than has the same size on both sides and that can the converted (or casted without data loss) to/from `size_t`

Edit 2:

I'm saving my data in the following format:

```
(size_of_data_chunk)(data_chunk)(size_of_data_chunk)(data_chunk)...
```

Common code:

Code in kernel land:

```
void add_chunk(membuffer *buffer, void *chunk, size_t size){

    if(buffer->data != NULL){
        buffer->data = krealloc(buffer->data, buffer->len + sizeof(size_t) + size, GFP_KERNEL);
        buffer->len += sizeof(size_t) + size;

        memcpy(buffer->data + buffer->len, &size, sizeof(size_t));
        memcpy(buffer->data + buffer->len + sizeof(size_t), chunk, size);
    }else{

        buffer->data = kmalloc(sizeof(size_t) + size, GFP_KERNEL);
        buffer->len = sizeof(size_t) + size;

        memcpy(buffer->data, &size, sizeof(size_t));
        memcpy(buffer->data + sizeof(size_t), chunk, size);

    }

}
```

Code in user land:

```
void *get_chunk(membuffer *buffer){

    size_t *size;
    void *new_buffer;
    void *chunk = NULL;

    size = malloc(sizeof(size_t));

    memcpy(size, buffer->data, sizeof(size_t));

    chunk = malloc(*size);
    memcpy(chunk, buffer->data + sizeof(size_t), *size);

    buffer->data = malloc(buffer->len - sizeof(size_t) - *size);

    memcpy(buffer->data, buffer->data + sizeof(size_t) + *size, buffer->len - sizeof(size_t) - *size);

    free(size);

    return chunk;
}
```

Note that I know what type of data will be contained on each chunk, so I don't need to save the type nor any other information, just the size of the chunk, and the chunk per-se.

Also note that this is my not-yet-finished (aka test) code. Maybe some `free`'s are missing.

Comment: When you say a "raw memory block" exactly what mechanism are you using (on both sides)?

Comment: That's not really what I meant.  How are you allocating the memory in userspace and then how are you attempting to access it in kernel space?  What are the specific systems calls you are using?

Comment: @BenjaminLeinweber Oh, sorry. :edit:

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you see `size_t` isn't guaranteed to be the same ?

Comment: @cnicutar I was just told so by user named ```vad``` in ##kernel

Comment: Have you considered just using a fixed size `uint64_t` or something ?

Comment: @cnicutar Can I convert ```uint64_t``` to/from ```size_t``` without data loss?

Comment: Probably yes, but it's not ideal.

Comment: @cnicutar I'm guessing ```uint64_t``` will always be bigger than ```size_t``` (is that right?), and I'm sure that I won't have sizes bigger than ```size_t```. If those two assumprions are right, is there any problem doing it that way?

Comment: Well, that's the thing I'm not sure about: whether `uint64_t` is always bigger than `size_t` - the standard doesn't guarantee it.

Comment: `size_t` is defined as `__kernel_size_t` in the kernel which is indeed architecture dependent (http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.33/include/linux/types.h#L59).  However, I would think that `size_t` should be consistent on an architecture basis between glibc and the kernel.

Comment: What really has me curious is how you are calling your kernel-space `add_chunk()` function from your user-space application.

Comment: @BenjaminLeinweber I'm not concerned at all about it not having the same size on different machines as I'm de/serializing data without exporting it from the machine where it was serialized.

Comment: @BenjaminLeinweber no, ```add_chunk``` is called only by the kernel (in fact, by a kernel module of mine)

Answer (score 1):

After looking at this for a while, it seem that `size_t` is a little weird.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119370/where-do-i-find-the-definition-of-size-t) quotes Wikipedia (though it looks like the quoted text is not there anymore) as saying that `size_t` is defined in `stdlib.h` via `stddef.h`.  I checked my Ubuntu 12.04 install and indeed:

```
/* Get size_t, wchar_t and NULL from <stddef.h>.  */
#define     __need_size_t
#ifndef __need_malloc_and_calloc
# define    __need_wchar_t
# define    __need_NULL
#endif
```

The `stddef.h` file is quite complicated, so I will not quote it here, but it appears to `typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t` which is also defined external.  I haven't traced it back much further, since it's getting sticky.

In the end, I believe that `size_t` should be consistent across a given architecture, be it the kernel or glibc.

On my 32-bit Ubuntu install, `sizeof(size_t)` consistently returns 4, whether from a user application or a hello world kernel loadable module.

Comment: Ok, I'll re-test my code, but the first several tests returned different values (not the size of ```size_t```, but the value I get when I serialize-deserialize). Do you see something wrong in my code?

Comment: Your code isn't showing how your userspace is passing data to the kernel space.  I have an idea what might be going on, but I would need to see that first.

Comment: I'm sending the data via netlink. Netlink received a length and a pointer to a block of memory. On the user side, the block is passed to the callback funciton. I'm assuming the mem block is passed correctly.

Comment: Hmm... I usually use IOCTLs, not netlink so I'm not so familiar.  Isn't the size of the data you're sending part of the netlink interface?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I must say to netlink "look, I'm giving you a pointer to a block of memory with a size of X, send it to userland"

Comment: http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/7356/print. It looks like this (admittedly old and possibly out of date) article defines a particular header you must use with a length field at a fixed 32-bits (which has nothing to do with size_t).  Am I missing something?