# size_t type not resolved but other types definitions in stddef.h available

Tags: c, eclipse-kepler, size-t

I am having a rather odd problem with my C project. I need to use a variable of type size_t.

For this purpose, I have included stddef.h, but my environment (Kepler) is unable to resolve type size_t. I spent efforts in verifying the include paths and indexer settings - but it wasn't quite necessary as I just found out that the other two types namely ptrdiff_t and wchar_t are being declared without any error. Kepler doesn't make any issue when I declare a variable of one of these two types. Anyone has any idea what could be wrong?

Might be relevant: I am having this problem with this project only (which is on git repository). Other projects that are not, don't have any such problem. 
Also, I haven't done any editing in stddef.h :)

Comment: Post your code, may be a syntax problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where do I find the definition of size\_t?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119370/where-do-i-find-the-definition-of-size-t)

Comment: @MrMojoRisin I don't think so. Reading the answers of that question didn't help solve my problem. Kindly read my question again.

Comment: @Yann if it was a syntax problem, the other two types wouldn't be declared. Please correct me if wrong?

Comment: @user3729534 It seems that you are true, but also can you provide us some informations about your software context OS, editor etc. And it __always__ can be a syntax problem, maybe you fail to write correctly size_t in your code, I can't even know this because you don't show us your source code (or at least the part you saw the unknow type error and the include part) ;) Ty

Comment: Can you compile your project ? It might just be Eclipse indexing that goes out of whack - which is very common, and rarely have any sane solution. So, nothing's really wrong regarding your compiler, but Eclipse is just being buggy.

Comment: Have you examined the contents of the file stddef.h to assure the definition of size_t exits?