# Does it matter which header (cstddef, cstdio, cstdlib, etc.) I include to get the definition of size_t?

Tags: c++, header, c++17, size-t, g++4.8

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t , the type `size_t` is defined in many header files: cstddef, cstdio, cstdlib, etc.

While writing my own code which header file should I include to use `size_t`?

This might seem like a trivial question, but as a beginning of C++ I am concerned about the following:

- Can I include any header file and be sure that `size_t` would behave in the same way regardless of which header file I included?
- Are there any surprises I need to be aware of like including one header file would have surprising side-effects that including another header file would not have?
- Is there a coding convention or popular convention or practice regarding this that leads to most people including a specific header file to get the definition of `size_t`?

Comment: Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119370/where-do-i-find-the-definition-of-size-t) you'll find your answer

Comment: @shantanusingh I don't see the answer to my question at the link you provided. Can you point me to the answer that discusses whether there are pros and cons or surprises I need to consider while including a specific header file to get `size_t`?

Comment: In **C**, a header introduces all the functions and definitions as specified for that header. It may introduce more, but those reside in the namespace reserved for the implementation (leading `__` or leading `_` with uppercase letter). In C++, headers are allowed to include *other* headers, but then again, in C++ you get the namespace `std::` so that should not be a problem. You usually go with whatever header you need to include anyway for whatever you are doing in your program.

Comment: `<cstddef>` is slightly smaller than the others, so if you don't need anything else...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I include any header file and be sure that `size_t` would behave in the same way regardless of which header file I included?

Yes.

> Are there any surprises I need to be aware of like including one header file would have surprising side-effects that including another header file would not have?

No.

> Is there a coding convention or popular convention or practice regarding this that leads to most people including a specific header file to get the definition of `size_t`?

I personally prefer `<cstddef>` but I am not aware of any conventions.

Comment: @user202729, I don't think that is necessary. The question is not about where you can find the definition of `size_t`. The post already contains that.

Comment: I see you made an edit in your answer to change your preference from `<cstdint>` to `<cstddef>`. Did your preference change now while writing the answer or was the earlier answer a typo? What led to this change?

Comment: @LoneLearner, I don't know whether to call it a typo. It's more like the mind and fingers were not in sync.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a coding convention or popular convention or practice
>   regarding this that leads to most people including a specific header
>   file to get the definition of size_t?

No, there's not or at least none that popular that I know of. Personally, in cases where I only need `std::size_t`, in order not to drag unnecessary code from the headers that define `std::size_t`, I define my own `size_t` as:

```
using size_t = decltype(sizeof(char));
```

Note: The above also complies with the standard definition of `std::size_t`.

Comment: A useful note IMHO is that your own definition appears to be *the* definition, at least according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) so there's are pretty good chance it's the standard definition.

Comment: @luk32 Note added thnx