# Remove first and last character from a string

Tags: c, c-strings

The task should be simple, remove first and last characters.

https://www.codewars.com/kata/56bc28ad5bdaeb48760009b0/train/c

The function gets two parameter (`dst` as destination and `src` as source), and should return a modified string and assign to `dst` pointer (if I understood correctly).

My Answer looks correct to me, but here is my problem:

When the string has more then 9 characters, the modified string comes with some symbols.

```
char* remove_char(char* dst, const char* src){

  memmove(dst,src+1,strlen(src+1)-1);


  return dst;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Do you know the difference between C string and an arbitrary array of characters?

Comment: Also note that `memmove` returns `dst`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Nope, not really

Comment: c-string is an array of non-zero characters, terminated by one single zero (known as null-terminator). This way string manipulation functions "know" where the string is ending. As the answer below is pointing out, you forgot to place the terminator in the right place.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When doing this:

```
memmove(dst,src+1,strlen(src+1)-1);
```

You're correctly skipping the first and last character, but you end up with a string that has no NUL terminator (`\0`). You should add it by yourself before or after the `memmove`:

```
size_t len = strlen(src) - 2;
memmove(dst, src + 1, len);
dst[len] = '\0';
```

Of course, all of the above code assumes that `dst` was correctly allocated and can contain at least `strlen(src) - 1` characters and that `src` has at least `2` characters.

If you also want to account for the edge case in which `src` is shorter than two characters:

```
size_t len = strlen(src);

if (len < 2) {
    *dst = '\0';
} else {
    memmove(dst, src + 1, len - 2);
    dst[len - 2] = '\0';
}

return dst;
```

Note: you might have to `#include <stddef.h>` to use `size_t`.

Comment: So basically String ( declared as pointer) behaves like an array ?

Comment: @michael1995 a string *is* an array. The only difference between a string and a normal character array is that a string is always terminated with the NUL-terminator `\0`.

Comment: size_t is defined in `<string.h>`, no need for `<stddef.h>`

Comment: @chqrlie isn't it the opposite? I.E. string.h includes stddeff.h which is where size_t is defined. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119370/where-do-i-find-the-definition-of-size-t

Comment: There's no need to include `<stddef.h>` for `size_t` because `<string.h>` must have been included to use `memmove()` and `strlen()`, and `string.h>` also defines `size_t`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler try running the program using the link provided by OP and you'll see that stddef is needed. I added that clarification only because of this. Sure it'a already included in string.h but I don't know what's the deal with that online compiler.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: `size_t` is defined in multiple standard include files: `<stddef.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<string.h>`, `<time.h>`, `<uchar.h>`, `<wchar.h>`, and many other system specific headers. If the code uses `memmove`, it should include `<string.h>` hence `size_t` will be defined. Technically, including just `<stddef.h>` will cause `size_t` to be defined and calling `memmove` without a prototype might not prevent compilation, but it is highly advisable to always include the proper header files and to enable all warnings.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: testing with the online compiler indeed shows the above code compiles with either `<stddef.h>` or `<string.h>`. Changing the code to `memmove((long)dst, src + 1, (char*)(len - 2));` compiles fine with both header files and passes the tests, proving that the online compiler is configured with very lenient  settings, only failing on errors and suppressing basic warnings. A very bad choice for beginners. One can choose which compiler to use, but cannot add any command line flags such as `-W -Wall -Werror` which should be the default.

Answer (score 3):

This call

```
memmove(dst,src+1,strlen(src+1)-1);
```

does not make a string in the character array pointed to by the pointer dst because the terminating zero is not copied and the destination array can not be zero-initialized.

Also the expression `strlen( src + 1 ) - 1` can invoke undefined behavior.

And there is no sense to use memmove provided that the character arrays are not overlapped.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the task can be performed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * remove_char( char * restrict dst, const char * restrict src )
{
    size_t n = strlen( src );

    n = n < 2 ? 0 : n - 2;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        memcpy( dst, src + 1, n );
    }

    dst[n] = '\0';

    return dst;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    char dst[N];

    printf( "\"%s\"\n", remove_char( dst, "" ) );
    printf( "\"%s\"\n", remove_char( dst, "1" ) );
    printf( "\"%s\"\n", remove_char( dst, "12" ) );
    printf( "\"%s\"\n", remove_char( dst, "121" ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
""
""
""
"2"
```

Comment: Why it is better to use  memcpy instead of memove?

Comment: @michael1995 memmove is a more complicated function that is it is less efficient compared to .memcpy.

Comment: memmove has different guarantees than memcpy. You're effectively changing the function's guarantees

Comment: @Ayxan If there is a need to change the original string then the function should be declared differently and have only one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple problems:

- it fails because you do not set the null terminator at the end of the destination array.
- it is brittle because you do not test the length of the source string to be at least 2 bytes, causing undefined behavior on shorter strings.
- it compiles by chance because you do not include `<string.h>` and thus call functions without a proper prototype. The prototypes inferred by the compiler are incorrect.

The *Solution* posted on the codewars online compiler should compile as a stand alone file. It must include the relevant files, such as `<string.h>` if you use `memmove()` or `strlen()`.

Here is a corrected solution:

```c
#include <string.h>

char *remove_char(char *dst, const char *src) {
    size_t len = strlen(src);
    if (len >= 2) {
        memmove(dst, src + 1, len - 2);
        dst[len - 2] = '\0';
    } else {
        *dst = '\0';
    }
    return dst;
}
```