# Is size_t guaranteed to be an alias type to one of integer types?

Tags: c++, types, typedef, template-specialization, size-t

Or can it be a separate unsigned integer type?

I have different specializations of a template function for different (unsigned) integer types. Do I need to provide a separate specialization for `size_t`?

Comment: You said "template function", so I removed the unrelated `c` tag.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/size_t/ it seems to be an alias, although I don't have the standard. If this is correct http://stackoverflow.com/a/1089181/3093378, then it is always an `unsigned` type, but not sure if it is always an alias.

Comment: I looked at that post. It does not say that `size_t` is defined as an alias. So can it be, for instance a 64-bit unsigned, and behave exactly as `unsigned long`, but not defined as `typedef unsigned long size_t` and be a stand-alone type? Or is it always an alias?

Comment: On my platform (OS X Mavericks, g++4.9), if I provide 2 different template specializations, one for `unsigned long` and one for `size_t`, I get a `redefinition error`, so `size_t` is an alias for `unsigned long`. Although cannot find anywhere that this is indeed the case in the standard. Good question.

Comment: @vsoftco I get same on linux, so I do not specialize for `size_t`. I am wondering, if it's always portable or on some platform, where it is not a `typedef`, there will be a problem

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I wrote about templates to explain why I got this question in the first place. But the question makes sense for C as well

Comment: It is related to the largest contiguous amount of memory the system can address. People often *incorrectly* assume it has the same size as a data pointer. Probably because the `offsetof` macro is defined using it, and they think that gives a pointer for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C++ Standard says:

> 18.2/2 The contents are the same as the Standard C library header , with the following changes:
>
> 18.2/6 The type size_t is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object.
>
> 18.2/7 [ Note: It is recommended that implementations choose types for ptrdiff_t and size_t whose integer
>   conversion ranks (4.13) are no greater than that of signed long int unless a larger size is necessary to
>   contain all the possible values. —end note ]

So, it *doesn't* say explicitly whether the implementation-defined unsigned integer type will be one of `unsigned short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`.  The fact that 18.2/6 exists and specifies an "implementation-defined unsigned integer type" may be seen to override 18.2/2's default of following C, so any answer for C can't be trusted for C++.

The recommendation re conversion ranks implies the `size_t` will be expected to be one of the types mentioned in 4.13, where `size_t` isn't explicitly mentioned but the obvious candidates are, but that's no guarantee.

> Do I need to provide a separate specialization for size_t?

You could use `std::is_same` and `std::enable_if` to do so when `size_t` is a distinct type....

Comment: `std::is_same` and `std::enable_if` solves it. thanks

Comment: Although the cited specifications could indeed be taken as overriding the general rule of following C, there is in fact no discrepancy here between C++ and any version of standard C published to date.  Recent versions of C even have the same note.

Answer (score 4):

Text from `[support.types]`:

> The contents are the same as the Standard C library header , with the following changes:
>
> The type size_t is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object.

From the C99 specification of stddef.h there is also this footnote for clarification:

> 224) Some of these types may denote implementation-defined extended integer types.

Since the C++ standard text does not specifically say that `size_t` must be a typedef, and since it appears to be based on C99, it seems to me that we should conclude that it may be an implementation-defined extended integer type.

Having said that, I don't know of any implementation for which it is not a typedef.

I'm not sure what you should do about your overload problem, however note that it is not limited just to `size_t`; there is also `ptrdiff_t`, and all of the fixed-width integer types. The latter are specified as being `typedef`s, however they are allowed to be aliases for extended integer types.

Answer (score 0):

From the standard (§ 18.2) from **N3797** published on 13.10.2013:

> The type size_t is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the 
>       size in bytes of any object.

So it must be an *unsigned* integral type, but the actual size is implementation defined.

Comment: I don't see where it says that it is an alias to some unsigned integer type.

Comment: @user2052436, see the reference.

Comment: @RakibulHasan your post is unclear. By starting with "Yes" it looks as if you are answering "Yes" to the title of OP's question (when in fact the answer to the title is "No", but the answer to the first line of his post body is "Yes").

Comment: @MattMcNabb, My *Yes* refers to the question in title. I assumed, from this other answered could be derived easily.

Comment: IDK how you get "yes" from the quoted text. It clearly does not specify that `size_t` must be a typedef for another type.

Comment: -1 ambiguity, -1 incorrectness, +1 standards quote with actual answer.

Answer (score -4):

Yes. It is.

I am pretty certain it is an alias of `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide any references to support your answer?

Comment: `unsigned long long` is true on Windows x64, but on most other mainstream platforms it's a typedef for `unsigned long`.  But it's *not* guaranteed that it's the same type as any of the standard types; it's allowed to be an implementation-defined extended integer type.