# Is there any difference between size_t and unsigned long long?

Tags: c++, c, format-specifiers, size-t, unsigned-long-long-int

I am a bit confused about the difference between **size_t** and **unsigned long long**. Is there any difference between them at all?

Also when printing or scanning a size_t object for input/output, will it be appropriate to use **%llu** (unsigned long long's format specifier)?

Comment: `size_t` tends to change based on the architecture you're compiling for.

Comment: Yes, there is a difference. `unsigned long long` is a primitive type and `size_t` is a typedef  to a type, usually to `unsigned long long`. Other systems can typedef it differently.

Comment: dupe of [Where do I find the definition of size\_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119370/where-do-i-find-the-definition-of-size-t) or [Is size_t guaranteed to be an alias type to one of integer types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749822/is-size-t-guaranteed-to-be-an-alias-type-to-one-of-integer-types) or etc.

Comment: Both the [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) have the `z` prefix for `size_t`. So to properly scan for or print a `size_t` value use e.g. `%zu`.

Comment: `size_t` is an implementation-defined type that's large enough to hold the size of any object.  End of story.  It's **NOT** the same thing as `unsigned long long`.  `size_t` is `size_t` and the correct format specifier is `%zu`.

Comment: The definition of `size_t` is platform dependent. On a 64 bit platform it's usually `unsigned long long`, on a 32 bit platform it's usually `unsigned long`.

Comment: Or in the case of C++ don't use either `scanf` nor `printf`. Instead use `std::cin` and `std::cout` with the standard input and output operator `>>` and `<<`, and the right thing will be done without having to worry about format specifiers.

Comment: Please one question per question

Comment: On my machine, `std::size_t` is smaller than `unsigned long long`.  `%llu` is inappropriate for `std::size_t`, rather use `%zu`.