# Convert size_t to integer

Tags: c, gmp

I'm working with moderately sized integers which are of a size so that their logarithm would be an int. I'm using the GNU Multiprecision library (GMP) with the C programming language.

I wonder whether there exists a function that would convert the data type size_t into an int.

Comment: `(int)size_t_variable`

Comment: Convert? `size_t` is an integer type.

Comment: you need to cast it as @pmg mentioned. Remember that on many systems `sizeof(size_t) > sizeof(int)` and it is an unsigned integer type

Comment: I swear I searched for the term "size_t" using the above search bar. I quit when it showed results for an unrelated programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Source: [src](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23749908/10075467)
size_t is implementation dependent yeah, and it's size may vary. You can try to typecast it to int but that may not be able to store as you already mentioned indirectly.
But still you can work with strings

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    size_t x = 123456789012345678LL;
    std::cout<<(x)<<" "<<int(x)<<" "<<to_string(x);
```

And then use:

```cpp
    mpz_init(n);
    mpz_set_ui(n,0);
    flag = mpz_set_str(n,x, 10);
    assert (flag == 0);
    printf ("n = ");
    mpz_out_str(stdout,10,n);
    printf ("\n");
}
```

(Never read about GMP before this question, but the approach should be correct. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: This is a C question. You can't use `cout` and `to_string`

Comment: I know that's what I mention the approach matters...

Comment: You can write a simple function to convert to string and to print... just got to understand meaning of word 'to_string' and he's already using GMP