# GMP: Extract the length of an integer, part II

Tags: c, gmp

This is a follow-up question of

[Convert size_t to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62504040/convert-size-t-to-integer)

I am trying to extract the length of an mpz_t, and by now I think that it would be best to have it as another mpz_t. Does there exist an analogue of mpz_sizeinbase(no, base) which returns an mpz_t?

Comment: With "length", do you mean how many bytes that data type occupies, or how long the decimal representation of the number is?
To now the length of a number in decimal before the decimal point you can usually use 1 + the logarithm base 10 of the number. I'm not sure about number of digits after the decimal point, possibly this can't be calculated as in some cases it's infinite (e.g. in the case of 1/3).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but efficiency does play a role here, so that I would be most pleased with not applying any "higher maths" function. For my application, the base of the representation does not matter at all; I can easily change a different number to cancel out any base change. As to the number of decimal places, we are talking about an integer here, as indicated by the "mpz_t" data type; the data type for a rational number would have been "mpq_t".

Comment: Besides, unfortunately, it seems as though GMP does not contain a logarithm function, apart from mpz_sizeinbase.

Comment: Please answer BrechtSander's question: What do you mean by "length"?

Comment: Are you suggesting I should add the answer to that question to the post?