# Is std::size_t a distinct type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overloading, size-t

The C++ standard mentions this for `std::size_t`:

> The type `size_t` is an **implementation-defined unsigned integer type** that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object ([expr.sizeof]).

Now my question is that if this type is a distinct type from other unsigned int types or not. I mean, should I be able to have overloads like this or not:

```
void myfunc(std::uint16_t) {}
void myfunc(std::uint32_t) {}
void myfunc(std::uint64_t) {}
void myfunc(std::size_t) {}
```

Because if it is a distinct type, I should be able to have these overloads while if it is not, I should get redefinition error. I somehow always thought that `std::size_t` should be a distinct type but I currently get redefinition error which means it is not (at least in GCC and Clang)

The reason that I'm asking this is that I want to know if I have overload of a function for different unsigned int sizes, can I safely assume that one of them will be called for `std::size_t` or not.

Comment: @tadman `size_t` is normally size of pointer, so it my case it conflicts with `uint64_t` because system is 64 bit. I'm testing in gcc and clang.

Comment: Yeah, it's going to be mapped to an identical form of one of the existing types unless you're using a really oddball architecture where pointers aren't the same size as any conventional data type. Why would you need to handle `size_t` differently from, say, `uint64_t`? They should be effectively bit for bit identical.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: The remaining question is whether the behavior they've observed on one system is guaranteed by the standard on all systems. Can there exist a system in which `size_t` is *not* directly compatible/equivalent to some other defined `unsigned` type? I wouldn't be surprised if some old systems did not adhere to this (e.g. they might have 8 and 16 bit normal integer types, but 32 bit pointers and `size_t`s), but the systems I'm aware of like that are also pre-standard C++ IIRC, so systems like that might not be allowed by standard C++.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError It is important to know if it is distinct type. for example, `char` is a distinct type from `signed char` and `unsigned char` even though has the representation and signedness of one of them(implementation defined). So I can have 3 overloads for `char`, `unsigned char`, and `signed char` at same time. But I cannot find anything about `size_t`.

Comment: [There may also be implementation-defined extended integer types](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#def:type,extended_signed_integer) and `size_t` may well be one of those.

Comment: Why would you want to write distinct overloads for those? C++ has templates.

Comment: @n.m. yes, I normally use templates too for sure. I just want to know what should I expect in reality.

Comment: Related: [for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23749822/2057969) / [for C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75616653/2057969)

Comment: You can make your own distinct type of it, `enum class distinct_size_t : std::size_t {};`

Comment: Bit of interesting implementor trivia around this, the predefined macro `__STDCPP_­DEFAULT_­NEW_­ALIGNMENT__` must expand to an integer literal of type `std::size_t`, and prior to C++23, there was no literal suffix for `std::size_t`. This scenario makes it less trivial to make `std::size_t` a distinct type (since equating it to an existing type means you can simply use the suffix for that type, even if you have to choose a suffix based on the target like Clang does).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is size\_t guaranteed to be an alias type to one of integer types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749822/is-size-t-guaranteed-to-be-an-alias-type-to-one-of-integer-types)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Now my question is that if this type is a distinct type from other unsigned int types or not.

Your question heavily depends on what exactly you mean with "*unsigned int types*". I'll assume this to refer to "*unsigned integer types*" as defined by the standard.

It can *not* be a type distinct from other *unsigned integer types*. All *unsigned integer types* are listed exclusively in [[basic.fundamental]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.fundamental#2.sentence-3). These are the *standard unsigned integer types* `unsigned char`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long`, and *extended unsigned integer types* if the implementation defines any (which isn't usually the case in the most common C++ implementations).

If you intend "*unsigned int types*" to refer to the *standard unsigned integer types* listed above, then the answer becomes that `size_t` is neither required, nor prohibited, to be one of them, since it may also be one of the *extended unsigned integer types*. But if the implementation has none of those, then it must be one of the *standard unsigned integer types*.

If you intend "*unsigned int types*" to mean any "*integer types*" as defined in the standard which also have *unsigned* signdness, then the answer is again that it *cannot* be distinct from this set, since this set merely is a superset of the set of all *unsigned integer types*, adding `char8_t`, `char16_t`, `char32_t` and potentially `char` and `wchar_t` (which have implementation-defined signdness).

(You can find definitions for all the mentioned terms from the standard in [basic.fundamental]/1 to 11 of the post-C++20 ISO C++ draft N4868 I linked above.)

---

> Because if it is a distinct type, I should be able to have these overloads while if it is not, I should get redefinition error.

Regardless of the above, it is not guaranteed to cause a redefinition error, because while the types `uint16_t`, `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` also must be *unsigned integer types* from the same category, they don't have to cover the whole category and in fact cannot, because there are at least 5 *unsigned integer types*, but you listed only three `uintX_t` overloads. So `size_t` doesn't need to match any of them and in fact doesn't need to match any `uintX_t` at all.

For example on 64bit architectures, often `uint16_t` is `unsigned short`, `uint32_t` is `unsigned int` and `uint64_t` is either `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`, with the remaining one not being aliased by any `uintX_t`.

So the overload set is not safe. `size_t` may be one of the `uintX_t` or it may not and neither the whole `uintX_t` set, nor the whole set including `size_t` must cover the set of all unsigned integer types.

If you want to overload for all unsigned integer types, overload by the actual (non-alias) type names for the standard unsigned integer types listed above, as well as all extended unsigned integer types if your implementation has them. However, consider whether a template, possibly constrained with a type trait, isn't a better option instead, since you can't portably know about extended integer types.

Comment: As I mentioned in comments, I cannot find a way to declare *it cannot be a distinct type*. As an exception, `char` is a distinct type from `signed char` and `unsigned char` even though representation and signedness is one of them. SO we can have 3 overloads for `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` at same time. But it is not obvious for `size_t`. Should it be a distinct type or not from other unsigned intergers.

Comment: @Afshin "_I cannot find a way to declare it cannot be a distinct type._": I linked you the paragraph in the ISO C++ standard draft making it impossible. "_As an exception, char is a distinct type_": Yes, that is spelled out in the linked section as well. `char` is never an _unsigned integer type_, even if it is unsigned.

Comment: @Afshin And to clarify: Your question heavily depends on what exactly you mean with "_unsigned int types_". I assumed this to refer to "_unsigned integer types_" as defined by the standard in the link I provided. If you intended it to mean "_standard unsigned integer types_" as defined in the standard and listed in my answer, then the answer becomes that it is neither guaranteed that `size_t` is, nor isn't, any of them.

Comment: "extended unsigned integer types if the implementation defines any (which isn't usually the case in the most common C++ implementations)." - Wouldn't GCC's `unsigned __int128` count? Clang and ICC support it as well.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Only in `-std=gnu++XX` mode, not in `-std=c++XX` mode, see https://godbolt.org/z/b1j5r9dnq. If `__int128` was an extended integer type in the sense of the standard, then `uintmax_t` cannot be 64bit, but GCC will still define it as such (because changing `uintmax_t` has too many problematic implications). So GCC can't consider `__int128` an extended integer type in the sense of the standard if it wants to be standard conform.

Answer (score 6):

The C++ header `<cstddef>` in fact is same as the C `<stddef.h>`.

From the C++17 Standard

> 1 The contents and meaning of the header  are the same as the
> C standard library header <stdlib.h>, except that it does not declare
> the type wchar_t, and except as noted in 21.2.3, 21.2.4, 21.5,
> 23.10.11, 24.5.6,
> 28.8, 29.6.9, and 29.9.2.

In C the name size_t is defined as a macro

> 7.19 Common definitions <stddef.h>
>
> 1 The header <stddef.h> defines the following macros and declares the
> following types. Some are also defined in other headers, as noted in
> their respective subclauses. 2 The types are

```
ptrdiff_t
```

> which is the signed integer type of the result of subtracting two
> pointers;

```
size_t
```

> which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof
> operator;

Usually `size_t` is defined as an alias for the type `unsigned long`.

> 4 The types used for size_t and ptrdiff_t should not have an integer
> conversion rank greater than that of signed long int unless the
> implementation supports objects large enough to make this necessary

Comment: `std::size_t` is not a macro

Comment: @R.M. I provided a quote from the C Standard where size_t  is defined as a macro. Also I wrote that is defined as an alias for other integer type. So it is possible that in C++ it is indeed defined as an alias.

Comment: The quote is *defines the following macros **and** declares the following types* is saying that type declarations are separate from the CPP macros also defined in that header.  The "and" is separating two things, not telling you how the types are declared.  Normal implementations use `typedef` to define types, so you can't `#undef size_t` as @R.M. says.  For example, GCC's `stddef.h` uses `typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t;` after some `#ifdef` stuff to figure out what type to pick.

Answer (score 1):

No; there is no fixed list of types that don't mention `size_t` that is guaranteed by the standard to include `size_t`.

> The reason that I'm asking this is that I want to know if I have overload of a function for different unsigned int sizes, can I safely assume that one of them will be called for std::size_t or not.

Yes, you can make this guarantee.

Simply add

```
static_assert( size_t is one of (your fixed list) )
```

There are 3 major compilers.   You can learn how those 3 do this problem, and make a list of overloads that work for those compilers (possibly including `#ifdef` based tests; I honestly doubt it is needed).

Then you `static_assert` that your list contains `size_t.

In the event that your research becomes obsolete, your static assert fires.  Include a comment on what you should do in this case.

There are many ways to write that static assert.  The tricky part is making sure that your list of overloads matches the list of types there; I don't know of a clean way to do that.

If you are willing to make these overloads members (even static members) of a class, you can use template metaprogramming to make the overloads and do the `size_t` check.  It could even have a list of integers and conditionally add `size_t` if it isn't there, rather than check.