# Expanded from macro 'num' while printing it using printf by Clang compiler

Tags: c, gcc, macros, clang, c-preprocessor

Code:

```
char *color_name[] = {
    "red",
    "blue",
    "green"
};

#define color_num (sizeof(color_name)/sizeof(char*))

int main(){
    printf("size %d \n",color_num);
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine with GCC 4.8.2 on Centos 7.

But I got error running above program on mac which says:

```
note:expanded from macro 'color_num'
```

Compiler on my Mac:

```
……include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

I've been told that GCC has been linked to Clang on Mac when it is used to compile program, am I right?

**Qestion:**

So why does Clang report that error? Is that concerning pre-processing?

**And if I do this, it works fine:**

```
int a = color_num;
printf("%d\n",a);
```

**or:**

```
printf("%d\n",sizeof(color_num)/sizeof(char*));
```

UPDATA=============

```
Crayon_277@Macintosh 20150525$ gcc -g -o ex11 ex1.c
ex1.c:16:21: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'unsigned long' [-Wformat]
        printf("size %d\n",color_num);
                     ~~    ^~~~~~~~~
                     %lu
ex1.c:14:19: note: expanded from macro 'color_num'
#define color_num (sizeof(color)/sizeof(char*))
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

It seems no error but just that format warning.

I think it may concerning the extension I use for vim 
scrooloose/syntastic

I got error from that:

[image]

Comment: It would help if you could post the actual error message. The "note" is just there to help you understand the error, but it's not the error message itself.

Comment: That was to be expected. Actrually, gcc will also notify this, but it does require -Wformat which is included in -Wall. The latter is the least one should always enable (-Wextra recommended).

Comment: Note that a function without arguments shall be noted `f(void)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably complaining that the expression expanded from `color_num` is an unsigned (perhaps unsigned long) while the format in the printf is a signed integer.

`sizeof` gives `size_t`, which is always an unsigned type, as noted in *[is size_t always unsigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089176/is-size-t-always-unsigned)*, but the number of bits depends on the implementation.  Compiler warnings may — and often do — refer to the mismatch in terms of the equivalent type rather than `size_t` as such.  The C standard after all, does not specify the nature of diagnostic messages.

When you changed that to an assignment, it is less strict, since that is a different check.

The "note" lines are something that the compiler *adds* to a warning/error message to help you understand where the problem came from.

(As the comment notes, you should quote the entire warning message, to make the question understandable).

Comment: sizeof return size_t; leave it to the toolchain what that actually maps to.

Comment: @Olaf it does not return anything, it's an operator and it's evaluated at compile time.

Comment: Thomas: Just reference the standard: n1570, 6.5.3.4/5 . And for an assignment  - as for any other expression - default coercion rules are applied. However, gcc at least can (and should) are able to warn about some of those, too (-Wconversion e.g.).

Comment: @iharob: how about a VLA? Anyway, every operator is actually a function, which takes argument(s) and returns a result. sizeof is not different in that from the unary '-' for instance. Note that the time of evaluation does not change that. The standard very well allows the compiler to evaluate a function at compile-time if it can prove it constant/pure. And it actually does: just think of expressions. Note that the stndard explicitly mentions it "yields" (6.5.3.4/2, also for VLAs). For C I take this as the same; but I will not discuss about the difference between "yield" and "return" here

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof` gives the value with `size_t` type, the right format specifier for `size_t` is `"%zu"`.