# How to get string from an address?

Tags: c++

I have a ULONG value that contains the address.

The address is basically  of string(array of wchar_t terminated by NULL character)

I want to retrieve that string.

what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 7):

[@KennyTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197951/how-to-get-string-from-an-address/2197960#2197960)'s answer is right on the money if by "basically of a string" you mean it's a pointer to an instance of the `std::string` class. If you mean it's a pointer to a C string, which I suspect may be more likely, you need:

```
char *s = reinterpret_cast<char *>(your_ulong);
```

Or, in your case:

```
whcar_t *s = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t *>(your_ulong);
```

Note also that you can't safely store pointers in any old integral type. I can make a compiler with a 32-bit `long` type and a 64-bit pointer type. If your compiler supports it, a proper way to store pointers in integers is to use the `stdint.h` types `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`, which are guaranteed (by the C99 standard) to be big enough to store pointer types.

However, C99 isn't part of C++, and many C++ compilers (read: Microsoft) may not provide this kind of functionality (because who needs to write portable code?). Fortunately, `stdint.h` is useful enough that workarounds exist, and portable (and free) implementations of `stdint.h` for compatability with older compilers can be found easily on the internet.

Comment: Of course, I probably would have used a C-style cast, but that's because I'm a C programmer at heart.

Comment: For practical purposes, `size_t` is as big as a pointer if any integral type is.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - For practical purposes, yes, it will, but I actually asked a question a while ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464174/size-t-vs-intptr-t) about whether this was a kludge or a logical requirement. It turns out that, for _full_ portability, `size_t` is insufficient. Not so much for the present, but into the past, and possibly into the future (because who can predict that?).

Answer (score 3):

```
string& s = *reinterpret_cast<string*>(your_ulong);
```