# What is the correct type for array indexes in C?

Tags: c, types, indexing, c99

What type for array index in C99 should be used? It have to work on LP32, ILP32, ILP64, LP64, LLP64 and more. It doesn't have to be a C89 type.

I have found 5 candidates:

- `size_t`
- `ptrdiff_t`
- `intptr_t` / `uintptr_t`
- `int_fast*_t` / `uint_fast*_t`
- `int_least*_t` / `uint_least*_t`

There is simple code to better illustrate problem. What is the best type for `i` and `j` in these two particular loops. If there is a good reason, two different types are fine too.

```
for (i=0; i<imax; i++) {
        do_something(a[i]);
}
/* jmin can be less than 0 */
for (j=jmin; j<jmax; j++) {
        do_something(a[j]);
}
```

P.S.
In the first version of question I had forgotten about negative indexes.

P.P.S.
I am not going to write a C99 compiler. However any answer from a compiler programmer would be very valuable for me.

Similar question:

- [size_t vs. uintptr_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464174/size-t-vs-intptr-t)
  The context of this question if different though.

Comment: IMO there is no one correct type.  You pick what works "best" for you.  If performance matters, [you may have to use `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49326477/why-are-size-t-and-unsigned-int-slower-than-int) instead of some type someone else said is "correct".  But if you have to address an array larger than `int` can index. you will have to use something like `size_t`, `long long`, or `ptrdiff_t`.  I'd say if you care enough that it matters, you'll **benchmark** the different options for your code and pick the fastest.  Which can be significantly different on different platforms.

Comment: There is also `ssize_t`, which is what I'd use, in case I wasn't indexing the buffer from 0. But that's more of an edge case.

Comment: @Sahsahae Pedantically, `ssize_t` isn't a very good choice. [Per POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html): "The type `ssize_t` shall be capable of storing values at least in the range `[-1, {SSIZE_MAX}]`."

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I almost always use `size_t` for array indices/loop counters. Sure there are some special instances where you may want signed offsets, but in general using a signed type has a lot of problems:

The biggest risk is that if you're passed a huge size/offset by a caller treating things as unsigned (or if you read it from a wrongly-trusted file), you may interpret it as a negative number and fail to catch that it's out of bounds. For instance `if (offset<size) array[offset]=foo; else error();` will write somewhere it shouldn't.

Another problem is the possibility of undefined behavior with signed integer overflow. Whether you use unsigned or signed arithmetic, there are overflow issues to be aware of and check for, but personally I find the unsigned behavior a lot easier to deal with.

Yet another reason to use unsigned arithmetic (in general) - sometimes I'm using indices as offsets into a bit array and I want to use %8 and /8 or %32 and /32. With signed types, these will be actual division operations. With unsigned, the expected bitwise-and/bitshift operations can be generated.

Comment: The correct type is (signed) int. Indexes can be negative.

Comment: @EnzoR: `int` most definitely is not correct. Indices can be larger than `INT_MAX`. If you need a signed type for indices (for use relative to a pointer somewhere other than the first element of the array pointed into), it's `ptrdiff_t`, not `int`.

Comment: Do you have any reference to the standard, or is that your own idea?

Comment: @EnzoR: You do not need a reference to the standard to state a mathematical fact that 2^31-1 is less than 2^64-1.

Comment: Read the standard. In several points the array subscript is said to be a signed integer. In 6.5.6 example 10 it is explicitly written to be "int".

Comment: You always need to go to the standard! Otherwise you're just guessing or wishful thinking. For example, you cannot pass more than 127 arguments to a function. This is in the standard of the language.

Comment: @Enzo_R - you need a signed integer type, but not 'int'. int is, on most modern 64-bit platforms, a 32-bit value, which is insufficient to represent the possible indexes of an array on a 64-bit platform. Just because an example uses 'int' doesn't mean that's actually the best type. The previous comment already cited a feature of the standard, ptrdiff_t, which is a much better answer than int, because it is a signed integer type that is automatically sized to the pointer size of the platform.

Answer (score 45):

I think you should use `ptrdiff_t` for the following reasons

- Indices can be negative. Therefore for a general statement, all unsigned types, including `size_t`, are unsuitable.
- The type of `p2 - p1` is `ptrdiff_t`. If `i == p2 - p1`, then you should be able to get `p2` back by `p2 == p1 + i`. Notice that `*(p + i)` is equivalent to `p[i]`.
- As another indication for this "general index type", the type of the index that's used by overload resolution when the builtin `operator[]` (for example, on a pointer) competes against a user-provided `operator[]` (for example vector's) is exactly that (http://eel.is/c++draft/over.built#16):
  >

  > For every cv-qualified or cv-unqualified object type T there exist candidate operator functions of the form
  >
  > ```
  > T*      operator+(T*, std::ptrdiff_t);
  > T&      operator[](T*, std::ptrdiff_t);
  > T*      operator-(T*, std::ptrdiff_t);
  > T*      operator+(std::ptrdiff_t, T*);
  > T&      operator[](std::ptrdiff_t, T*);
  > ```

EDIT: If you have a *really* big array or a pointer to a really big memory portion, then my "general index type" doesn't cut it, as it then isn't guaranteed that you can subtract the first element's address from the last element's address. @Ciro's answer should be used then https://stackoverflow.com/a/31090426/34509 . Personally I try to avoid using unsigned types for their non-ability to represent negative edge cases (loop end-values when iterating backwards for example), but this is a kind of religious debate (I'm not alone in that camp, though). In cases where using an unsigned type is required, I must put my religion aside, of course.

Comment: What do you mean with "indices can be negative"? Not when actually indexing, surely?

Comment: @unwind, sure why not? `int a[10]; int *pa = a+1; pa[-1] = 0;`. Array indexing is nothing but pointer arithmetic, and C doesn't care about the value you give. Using an unsigned index type will fail for many completely legal index operations.

Comment: @unwind - Depends on whether you're doing something weird. For instance, I have some arrays in my project that are indexed relative to some zero point - zero represents "now", positive indices represent future times, and negative indices are for past times.

Comment: It's also useful for having a sentinel value below zero. But really, the usecase is irrelevant if the questioner aims for a type that will work for any and all scenarios. What's important is really that unsigned types are the wrong choice.

Comment: @Johannes: Yeah, should have been clearer about that, I guess. I think I consider it a "special case", where you've done some work to make sure that negative indices are okay, by moving the 0-point of the array. Fine.

Comment: @unwind since array indexing in fact is just pointer indexing in the end, if you choose a unsigned index type that is used for "array" indexing, you also choose it for applying on pointers (it's always applied to pointers anyway, because of the implicit conversion). Having a negative index for pointers is quite common. It depends on what exactly the questioner looks for. His question first sounds like he wants to be really generic about it (like writing a C99 compiler) but then it drives into a direction where he is only interested in making a single loop working. I don't know.

Comment: It seems that PTRDIFF_MAX may be smaller that SIZE_MAX , so this may fail for a large array: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31090426/895245 `p1 + i` is not a pointer difference: it is pointer + int.

Comment: We have `ssize_t` for that :) People always seem to forget this one.

Comment: @Sahsahae I disagree for the reasons pointed out in my answer.

Answer (score 18):

Since the type of `sizeof(array)` (and `malloc`'s argument) is `size_t`, and the array can't hold more elements than its size, it follows that `size_t` can be used for the array's index.

**EDIT**
This analysis is for 0-based arrays, which is the common case. `ptrdiff_t` will work in any case, but it's a little strange for an index variable to have a pointer-difference type.

Comment: This is not quite correct.  sizeof(array) evaluates to the size of the array in bytes, *not* the number of elements. ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 §6.5.3.4.6

Comment: @Chris: I didn't say sizeof(array) is the number of elements.

Comment: I would also complement with the fact that `sizeof` is `size_t`, which also limits the size of declared arrays to `size_t`.

Comment: size_t is for dealing with byte counts, ptrdiff_t is for dealing with element counts (and thus array indices)

Answer (score 13):

**`size_t`**

If you start at `0`, use `size_t` because that type must be able to index any array:

- `sizeof` returns it, so it is not valid for an array to have more than `size_t` elements
- `malloc` takes it as argument, as mentioned by Amnon

If you start below zero, then shift to start at zero, and use `size_t`, which is guaranteed to work because of the reasons above. So replace:

```
for (j = jmin; j < jmax; j++) {
    do_something(a[j]);
}
```

with:

```
int *b = &a[jmin];
for (size_t i = 0; i < (jmax - jmin); i++) {
    do_something(b[i]);
}
```

Why **not** to use:

- **ptrdiff_t**: the maximum value this represents may be smaller than the maximum value of `size_t`.

  This is mentioned [at cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/ptrdiff_t), and the possibility of undefined behavior if the array is too large is suggested at C99 6.5.5/9:

  > When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
  >   or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the
  >   subscripts of the two array elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined,
  >   and its type (a signed integer type) is ptrdiff_t defined in the  header.
  >   **If the result is not representable in an object of that type, the behavior is undefined**.

  Out of curiosity, `intptr_t` might also be larger than `size_t` on a segmented memory architecture: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1464194/895245

  GCC also imposes further limits on the maximum size of static array objects: [What is the maximum size of an array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386979/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-array-in-c/31864574#31864574)
- **uintptr_t**: I'm not sure. So I'd just use `size_t` because I'm more sure :-)

See also:

- C++ version of this question: [Type of array index in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111357/type-of-array-index-in-c)

Comment: Sometimes, you might want to offset the array and keep sentinel values in the start of it (sadly I don't have real use case for this, frankly, I'd never do it myself), so "0" might be offset from array, not a real beginning, in that case you might also use `ssize_t`, why? Because that's signed version of `size_t`, and I'm also not so sure about other types.

Answer (score 5):

My choice: **ptrdiff_t**

Many have voted for `ptrdiff_t`, but some have said that it is strange to index using a pointer difference type. To me, it makes perfect sense: the array index is the difference from the origin pointer.

Some have also said that `size_t` is right because that is designed to hold the size. However, as some have commented: this is the size in bytes, and so can generally hold values several times greater than the maximum possible array index.

Answer (score 3):

In your situation, I would use `ptrdiff_t`. It's not just that indicies can be negative. You might want to count down to zero, in which case signed types yield a nasty, subtle bug:

```
for(size_t i=5; i>=0; i--) {
  printf("danger, this loops forever\n);
}
```

That won't happen if you use `ptrdiff_t` or any other suitable signed type. On POSIX systems, you can use `ssize_t`.

Personally, I often just use `int`, even though it is arguably not the Correct Thing To Do.

Comment: `while (i-- > 0)` is the idiomatic down-to-zero loop

Comment: `ssize_t` is only guaranteed to hold values from `[-1..2^15-1]`.

Answer (score 3):

I use `unsigned int`. (though I prefer the shorthand `unsigned`)

In C99, `unsigned int` is guaranteed to be able to index any portable array. Only arrays of 65'535 bytes or smaller are guaranteed to be supported, and the maximum `unsigned int` value is at least 65'535.

From the public WG14 N1256 draft of the C99 standard:

> #### 5.2.4.1 Translation limits
>
> The  implementation  shall  be  able  to  translate  and  execute  at  least one  program  that contains at least one instance of every one of the following limits: (Implementations should avoid imposing fixed translation limits whenever possible.)
>
> (...)
>
> - 65535 bytes in an object (in a hosted environment only)
>
> (...)
>
> ### 5.2.4.2 Numerical limits
>
> An  implementation  is  required  to  document  all  the  limits  specified in  this  subclause, which are specified in the headers `<limits.h>` and `<float.h>`. Additional limits are specified in `<stdint.h>`.
>
> ### 5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types `<limits.h>`
>
> The values given below shall be replaced by constant expressions suitable for use in `#if` preprocessing directives. Moreover, except for `CHAR_BIT` and `MB_LEN_MAX`, the following shall be replaced by expressions that have the same type as would an expression that is an object of the corresponding type converted according to the integer promotions. Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute v
>   alue) to those shown, with the same sign.
>
> (...)
>
> - maximum value for an object of type `unsigned int` `UINT_MAX`                     65535 // 2^16 - 1

In C89, the maximum portable array size is actually only 32'767 bytes, so even a signed `int` will do, which has a maximum value of at least 32'767 (Appendix A.4).

From §2.2.4 of a C89 draft:

> ### 2.2.4.1 Translation limits
>
> The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least one program that contains at least one instance of every one of the following limits: (Implementations should avoid imposing fixed translation limits whenever possible.)
>
> (...)
>
> - 32767 bytes in an object (in a hosted environment only)
>
> (...)
>
> ### 2.2.4.2 Numerical limits
>
> A conforming implementation shall document all the limits specified in this section, which shall be specified in the headers `<limits.h>` and `<float.h>`.
>
> "Sizes of integral types `<limits.h>`"
>
> The values given below shall be replaced by constant expressions suitable for use in #if preprocessing directives. Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.
>
> (...)
>
> - maximum value for an object of type int `INT_MAX` +32767

Comment: "In C99, unsigned int is guaranteed to be able to index any portable array." --> Array index range is `[0...SIZE_MAX-1]`.  `UINT_MAX` may be far less than `SIZE_MAX`, so the guarantee is not so.

Comment: @chux read my answer again. The maximum portable array size is 65535 bytes, so the array index range is [0...65535]

Comment: Although maximum _portable_ object size is 65535 bytes, an array may be larger (though not portable) and `unsigned` insufficient to index all of it.  `size_t` is portable to index all arrays.  Even if portability of a large array is lost, portability of indexing is preserved.

Comment: Arguing about the "minimum maximum value" is often tricky, but this concept is used a lot in the C standard. Having a C implementation with 16 bit `int` and 32 bit `size_t` is entirely possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the maximum length of your array in advance you can use

- `int_fast*_t / uint_fast*_t`
- `int_least*_t / uint_least*_t`

In all other cases i would recommend using

- `size_t`

or

- `ptrdiff_t`

depending on weather you want to allow negative indexes.

Using

- `intptr_t / uintptr_t`

would be also safe, but have a bit different semantics.

Comment: @codymaxin Could You write something more about these bit different semantics?

Comment: intptr_t is an integer which has at least the size of a pointer so you can safely cast a pointer into intptr_t. Think of it as a numerical representation of a pointer.

Comment: `int_least*_t` should never be used for a single variable. It may be a slow-to-access type, and is intended only to be used in arrays where you need to save space but guarantee a certain minimum number of bits. On any sane platform, you could just request the exact size you need (8, 16, 32, or 64) but C99 allows implementations that have no type of a certain size, and thus `int_least*_t` exists to request the "next largest type".

Comment: @R: "`int_least*_t` should never be used for a single variable"--not true for small embedded systems. I've worked on processors with 512 bytes of memory.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `size_t` for array offsets, but if you want negative array indexing, use `int`. It is able to address the maximum sized-array guaranteed by C89 (32767 bytes).

If you want to access arrays of the maximum size guaranteed by C99 (65535 bytes), use `unsigned`.

See previous revisions for accessing arrays allowed, but not guaranteed, by C.