# Thread stack error

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I am having a problem in my code and am unable to figure it out. I have three threads, thread 1 takes input of two numbers in hex, thread 2 and 3 exchange these first two digits with the last two and print the result.

Error message:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'str' was corrupted.

```
DWORD WINAPI changevalue( LPVOID lpParam )
{
    WaitForSingleObject(inThread,INFINITE); //Input thread
    printf("thread 1 and 2 running \n");

    int num = 0;
    num = (int)lpParam;
    int i = 0;

    char str[10] ={0};
    char a,b;
    _itoa(num,str,16);

    while (str[i] != NULL)
    {
        i++; //Get location of last char..
    }
    //Exchange first two digits with last two.
    a = str[0];
    b = str[1];

    str[0] = str[i-2];
    str[1] = str[i-1];
    str[i-2] = a;
    str[i-1] = b;
    printf("num=%s\n",str);
    //long numl=strtol(str,&stop,16);
    //printf("num = %x\n", numl);
    //We can also take input to a string then manuplate it, and 
    //then print it in form of a string only.
    //But int is used since it is mentioned in the statement.
    printf("thread 1 and 2 exit......\n ");
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: A bad multithreading sample...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `lParam` is `0`, calling `_itoa(num, str, 16)` will result in the single-character string `"0"`.

In that case, `i` will be `1`, and `str[i - 2] = a` will write *before* the string, thus corrupting the stack.

More generally, values of `lParam` ranging from `0` to `15` (inclusive) will trigger the problem.

Comment: @pezcode, array indexing is pointer arithmetic, and pointer arithmetic is signed. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174850/type-for-array-index-in-c99/3174900#3174900).

Comment: @pezcode: C array indexing is just syntactic sugar for `*(E1+E2)`, where one of the expressions is of pointer type and the other is of integer type, so something like `(-2)["hello" + 2]` is perfectly valid and defined C.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, I see. Somehow I thought operator[] has different behaviour.