# Type of array index in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, int, byte

What is the type of an array index in C#?

For example, in the code below, would the index be cast in an int before accessing the array element (third line)?

```
T[] myArray = new T[255];
byte index = 2;
T element = myArray[index];
```

If not, is it faster to access an array element by using an index of type 'byte' than an index of type 'int'?

Thanks

Comment: I'm amazed that this question seems to not have been asked before for C#. For completeness, it may be of interest to mention its counterparts in C++ (http://stackoverflow.com/q/8111357/96780) and "C99" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174850/type-for-array-index-in-c99).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Original answer:**

Yes, it's always an `int` for an array access expression. Other indexers (e.g. in `Dictionary<,>`) can have other parameter types, but an array access index is always `int`, via promotion if necessary (as per your example).

**But wait!**

Actually, looking at section 7.6.6.1 of the C# 5 specification, I'm not as sure:

> For an array access, the primary-no-array-creation-expression of the element-access must be a value of an array-type. Furthermore, the argument-list of an array access is not allowed to contain named arguments.The number of expressions in the argument-list must be the same as the rank of the array-type, and each expression must be of type `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, or must be implicitly convertible to one or more of these types.
>   The result of evaluating an array access is a variable of the element type of the array, namely the array element selected by the value(s) of the expression(s) in the argument-list.
>
> The run-time processing of an array access of the form P[A], where P is a primary-no-array-creation-expression of an array-type and A is an argument-list, consists of the following steps:
>
> - `P` is evaluated. If this evaluation causes an exception, no further steps are executed.
> - The index expressions of the argument-list are evaluated in order, from left to right. Following evaluation of each index expression, an implicit conversion (§6.1) to one of the following types is performed: `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`. The first type in this list for which an implicit conversion exists is chosen. For instance, if the index expression is of type `short` then an implicit conversion to `int` is performed, since implicit conversions from `short` to `int` and from `short` to `long` are possible. If evaluation of an index expression or the subsequent implicit conversion causes an exception, then no further index expressions are evaluated and no further steps are executed.

And indeed this code works:

```
string[] array = new string[10];
long index = 10;
string element = array[index];
```

So while *in your particular case* the `byte` would be promoted to `int`, access index access isn't always through an `int`.

Even with the "large arrays" support in .NET 4.5, I don't *think* that you can create an array with more than `int.MaxValue` elements, but I could be wrong. (I don't have time to test it right now, I'm afraid.)

Comment: In .NET 4.0 values larger than int.MaxValue fail.

Comment: Works with ulong for me! Thanks!

Comment: index must be less than 10, because length of array is 10 and indexing starts at 0

Comment: @RamilShavaleev: The point of the exercise was to test whether the compile-time type of the index had to be `int`, which it doesn't.