# Creating an array with different data types for index and elements

Tags: c#, arrays

I would like to create an array indexed with `Int16` values, with each element being an `SByte`.

If this is possible, How would I go about structuring my statement to achieve this?
This is what I have so far.

```
//This saves the array size after creation for reference by other functions in the class
public static Int16 ArraySize = 0;

//input array size input by user from UI, min 0, max 1024
public static void InitArray(Int16 inputArraysize)
{
    sbyte[] Arrayarray = new sbyte[inputArraysize];
    Array.ArraySize = inputArraysize;
    Debug.output("RAM ARRAY CREATED");
}
```

Comment: What you are asking for is not an array.

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you want to change .NET's array indexing type?

Comment: I plan to model RAM with the array, to some extent; I would like to be able to index values greater than 127, however, hence the 16 bit "Address bus" being used.

Comment: I see;
Do you know (in that case) How I can send the index as a variable, in that case?
I can't pass `inputRAMsize` as an `sbyte` due to the obvious constrictions in value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, you seem to think that an array type and its index type are related.

They are not. The index type is independent of the array type. [Arrays are always indexable with positive integers from 32 bits and upwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486533/type-of-array-index-in-c).

You're not very likely to be able to allocate arrays of 2 GB and larger though.

Comment: I believe I am mis-relating these (as you suggest) due to my attempts to pass the size value as an `SByte`;
Is there a way to pass it and create the value with an size greater than 127, in that case?

Comment: You're passing `inputArraySize` as `Int16` (I don't know why), so you can create an array of max 32767 elements.

Comment: Ah, I see:- I believe my issue lies elsewhere; Many thanks for your assistance.