# Two questions about basic C programs

Tags: c

1.

Set hasDigit to true if the 3-character passCode contains a digit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
   bool hasDigit;
   char passCode[50];

   hasDigit = false;
   strcpy(passCode, "abc");

   /* Your solution goes here  */

   if (hasDigit) {
      printf("Has a digit.\n");
   }
   else {
      printf("Has no digit.\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

What I tried (in place of /* Your solution goes here */ is:

```
if (isdigit(passCode) == true) {
    hasDigit = true;
}
else {
    hasDigit = false;
}
```

when testing

```
abc
```

it works, but when testing

```
a 5
```

it doesnt work.

2.

Replace any space ' ' with '_' in 2-character string passCode. Sample output for the given program:

1_

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
char passCode[3];

   strcpy(passCode, "1 ");

   /* Your solution goes here  */

   printf("%s\n", passCode);
   return 0;
}
```

What I put in place of /* Your solution goes here */ is:

```
   if (isspace(passCode) == true) {
      passCode = '_';
   }
```

And it fails to compile.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: `isdigit(...)` takes a character but you're passing an array.  Try looping over each character and passing `passCode[i]`

Comment: isdigit(passCode[i]) causes the compiler to tell me:


In file included from main.c:4:0: main.c: 

In function ‘main’: 

main.c:13:25: error: ‘i’ undeclared (first use in this function) 
    if (isdigit(passCode[i]) == true) { ^ main.c:13:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

Comment: also there is no need for `== true` if something is true the `if` will detect that

Comment: @SOMEK you will need to declare `int i;` and initialize it creating a `for(int i=0; i<3; i++)` loop to check each character in the array

Comment: Look at loop control in your text or tutorial. It's basic C (and just about any other language), and you'll do it for petty much the rest of your engineering career. The error is obvious: you didn't declare your loop-control variable `i` (if you even coded a loop at all; we don't know).

Comment: @cleblanc I made it work with multiple else if statements for each index. Can you elaborate on how the for loop with i works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you would use a for loop;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
   bool hasDigit;
   char passCode[50];

   hasDigit = false;
   strcpy(passCode, "abc");

   /* Your solution goes here  */
   for (int i=0; passCode[i]; i++)
       if (isdigit(passCode[i]))
           hasDigit = true;

   if (hasDigit) {
      printf("Has a digit.\n");
   }
   else {
      printf("Has no digit.\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this solution worked.

How do the i=0 and i++ parts of the for loop affect how it works?

Comment: The structure of a `for` loop is like this `for ( initial_condition; terminating_condition; post_action ) { body }`

Answer (score 2):

[`isdigit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isdigit.3.html) function takes an `int` as argument, not a `char *`. So you can't pass `passCode`. You'll have to loop over `passCode` and test each of the characters in `passCode` using `isdigit`.

For example:

```
bool hasDigit = false;

for (size_t i = 0; passCode[i]; ++i) {
    if (isdigit((unsigned char)passCode[i])) {
        hasDigit = true;
        break;
    }
}

...
```

Note that `isdigit` (and all `<ctype>` functions) doesn't necessarily return 1, so comparing with `true` is incorrect. Just check if it returns 0 or non-zero - that's what `isdigit` is documented to return.

You'll use a similar loop for the second problem and do:

```
for (size_t i = 0; passCode[i]; ++i) {
   if (isspace((unsigned char)passCode[i])) {
      passCode[i] = '_';
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked. What is the purpose of "size_t", and why does unsigned char have to be specified, and how does specifying it change the program?

Comment: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3174850/1275169 and 2. https://stackoverflow.com/q/21805674/1275169 answer both of your questions.

Comment: This good answer provides more information than the OP was perhaps asking.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm trying to learn as much as I can, so more info is awesome!