# Print a formatted array with "," and "{}"

Tags: c

I tried to print a formatted `int` array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 3
int arr[SIZE] = {1, 2, 3};

int main(void)
{   
    printf("{");
    for (int i =0; i < SIZE; i++ )
    {   
        printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("}");
    printf("\n");

}
```

but found it very hard

```
$ ./a.out
{1, 2, 3, }
```

Extra comma is appended.

Is it possible to accomplish such a task in a facile way?

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on what you found very hard to accomplish? It looks to me like you pretty much have what you are after, but just need to work out the kinks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that zero length arrays are not permitted in C (so `arr[0]` always exists), and you already have explicit code for the opening brace, this solution seems reasonable to me:

```
int main(void)
{   
    printf("{%d", arr[0]);
    for (size_t/*better type for array index*/ i = 1; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {   
        printf(", %d", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("}\n");
}
```

Reference: [What is the correct type for array indexes in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174850/what-is-the-correct-type-for-array-indexes-in-c)

Comment: @kiranBiradar: Nah, I mistyped it the first type round. Thanks for using the voting system properly: it's what it's for.

Comment: Aaah!! My eyes are fine then :D

Answer (score 2):

The below method does exactly without any `if` condition in `for` loop.

Idea is just loop till `i < SIZE-1` and print the last digit outside of the loop.

```
int i=0 ;
printf("{");
for (i =0; i < SIZE-1; i++ )
{
    printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
}
printf("%d}", arr[i]);
printf("\n");
```

Comment: This is the best way both in terms of readability and performance.

Comment: something like `SIZE-1` always scares me, in case something in the future sets `SIZE` as an unsigned type. But that could be paranoia, have an upvote all the same.

Comment: @Bathsheba Why would that matter?

Comment: `0UL - 1` is quite a big number innit. Personally I'd write `1 + i < SIZE` instead.

Comment: @Bathsheba Assuming that SIZE is a numeric constant as in the OP's example, it cant be zero, as arrays with size zero are not allowed. Otherwise if it's a variable taken as input, it would naturally have to be validated first. The important part here is to not teach newbies that they should write loops full of needless branching with `if` or `?:`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 3
int arr[SIZE] = {1, 2, 3};
int main(void)
{   
    printf("{");
    for (int i =0; i < (SIZE-1); i++ )
    {
        printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("%d}\n", arr[SIZE-1]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 3
int arr[SIZE] = {1, 2, 3};

int main(void)
{
    printf("{");
    for (int i =0; i < SIZE; i++ )
    {
    printf("%d", arr[i]);
        if(i < (SIZE - 1)){
            printf(", ");
        }
    }
    printf("}");
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The code needs to treat the first or the last element of the array as a special case. To treat the first element as special, the code should print a comma and space before each number, except for the first element when only the number is printed.

This can be accomplished with a ternary operator. Consider the ternary expression:

```
i ? ", " : ""
```

When `i` is not zero, the expression evaluates to a string that consists of a comma and a space. But when `i` is zero, the result is an empty string. So `i == 0` is the special case.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("{");
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%s%d", i ? ", " : "", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("}\n");
}
```