# What type is used in C++ to define an array size?

Tags: c++, avr

Compiling some test code in `avr-gcc` for an 8-bit micro-controller, the line

```
const uint32_t N = 65537;
uint8_t values[N];
```

I got the following compilation warning (by default should be an error, really)

```
warning: conversion from 'long unsigned int' to 'unsigned int' changes value from '65537' to '1' [-Woverflow]
uint8_t values[N];
```

Note that when compiling for this target, `sizeof(int)` is 2.

So it seems that, at an array size cannot exceed the size of an `unsigned int`.

Am I correct? Is this GCC-specific or is it part of some C or C++ standard?

Before somebody remarks that an 8-bit microcontroller generally does not have enough memory for an array so large, let me just anticipate saying that this is beside the point.

Comment: does AVR even have that much memory?

Comment: *this is beside the point.*

Comment: Are you certain that `size_t` is not defined for your environment? `size_t` is provided by the C language, not by the C++ Standard Library. `size_t` should still exist for your environment.

Comment: `size_t` should be defined in `<stddef.h>`.

Comment: [And a few other places.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) `size_t` is a bit of a skank.

Comment: C is not C++, and C++ is not C. `size_t` has nothing to do with "STL" (whatever that means). It:s a type defined in `stddef.h`. Every implementation must have it.

Comment: Indeed I find `size_t` in `stddef.h`. I thought it was a C++ `STL` definition.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I stand corrected.  Comment deleted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`size_t` is considered as the type to use, despite not being formally ratified by either the C or C++ standards.

The rationale for this is that the `sizeof(values)` will be that type (that *is* mandatated by the C and C++ standards), and the number of elements will be necessarily not greater than this since `sizeof` for an object is at least 1.

Comment: And a tricky question... what type is used when *indexing* an array?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The smartypants answer is to say `size_t` unless you have a negative index or the possibility of a negative index then it's a `ptrdiff_t`

Comment: it is possible to have a degenerate case where neither is correct. `ptrdiff_t` need not be wider than `size_t`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Go on, spill the beans.

Comment: @Eugene Whatever type *you* use. Any integral type can be used.

Comment: @n.m Indeed. A gripe with `std::vector` is that the overloaded operator `[]` can accept a floating point type as the argument.

Comment: `std::size_t` appears in the n465 draft and is listed in [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) as "since C++11". Is that wrong?

Comment: Well, that's the part of the "trickiness". Here is a question (C) for whoever is wondering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174850/what-is-the-correct-type-for-array-indexes-in-c

Comment: From n4659, 11.3.4 (Arrays): "If the constant-expression (8.20) is present, it shall be a converted constant
expression of type std::size_t" . That's all there is to it. Modulo conversion to an unsigned 16 bit value. Case closed.

Comment: How is this going to help OP? If they use `const size_t N = 65537;`, the warning on `uint8_t values[N];` should go away, but then they have the wrong size with no warning. Or do you expect a warning for `const size_t N = 65537;` even though unsigned operations wrap?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Occasionally your denigrating  rebukes cross over into trolling; you could make a more effective contribution than this - consider submitting an answer of your own for example? As the OP has accepted this answer (for now) its usefulness is demonstrated.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I did not write a rebuke. I wrote a genuine question. I do not see how this helps OP. You could simply explain.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I will not condescend to explain how the OP might have found this useful - that would be far better coming from them. Yes I concentrated more on the question title rather than the body but that’s harmless in the context of a site that works better if there are multiple answers, such as one that you might care to give.

Comment: It appears to me you have suggested changing code that provides a useful warning to code that may have no warning even though it defines an array incorrectly. This is a genuine concern, and I have no idea why you will not explain. As it stands, this answer is harmful and not useful.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That’s what the voting mechanism is for (and it’s a pity that this site only displays the net votes for the majority of viewers so masking any downvotes). I believe the correct course of action is for you to answer (which I am likely to upvote - such is the typical quality of your answers). It’s a pity that my answer can be read in a way that suggests any modification to the code the OP presents - that was far from my intention.

Comment: I can see that this answer literally answers the question OP wrote in their title, but there is more to their question. Given the example code in the question, simply answering that `size_t` is the type to use does not address the concerns about inadvertently getting an array of the wrong size. Taking the advice that `size_t` is the type to use could lead to the array having an undesired size with no warning. That is the problem I saw and is why I asked. There was no rebuke; I thought I might have missed something in your answer, so I inquired.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The compiler should warn about the narrowing conversion in an explicit assignment to `size_t` as well. It's not ill-formed any longer but defined behavior since `size_t` is unsigned; but even low warning levels should diagnose if a constant does not fit in the receiving type.

Answer (score 7):

> So it seems that, at an array size cannot exceed the size of an
>   `unsigned int`.

That seems to be the case *in your particular C[++] implementation*.

> Am I correct? Is this gcc-specific or is it part of some C or C++
>   standard?

It is not a characteristic of GCC in general, nor is it specified by either the C or C++ standard.  It is a characteristic of *your particular* implementation: a version of GCC for your specific computing platform.

The C standard requires the expression designating the number of elements of an array to have an integer type, but it does not specify a particular one.  I do think it's strange that your GCC seems to claim it's giving you an array with a different number of elements than you specified.  I don't think that conforms to the standard, and I don't think it makes much sense as an extension.  I would prefer to see it reject the code instead.

Comment: "size of an array" -> "number of elements in an array"?

Comment: I had used "size" following the OP's terminology.  Inasmuch as the context may have left that ambiguous, I have revised to "number of elements".

Comment: What will happen to `sizeof(array)` if `int array[SIZE_MAX];` ?

Comment: I'm uncertain what you're asking, @EugeneSh., if it remains an issue with the answer as it presently stands.  In particular, note that I do not anywhere say that an implementation cannot or should not limit the size in bytes or number of elements of an array.  I do say, however, that it should not give you an array with different dimension than you specify.  Instead, it should reject the code if it refuses to provide what you specify (or fail at runtime in the case of a VLA).

Comment: @JohnBollinger I guess my question was more motivated by the comments here (now seem to be removed). But it looks like `int array[SIZE_MAX];` can't be legal on *any* implementation?

Comment: Technically, @EugeneSh., I don't see that the standard forbids it, provided that `array` is never used as the operand of the `sizeof` operator.  In practice, however, I wouldn't expect compilers to accept such a declaration.

Answer (score 5):

I'll dissect the issue with the rules in the "incorrekt and incomplet" ISO CPP standard draft [n4659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf). Emphasis is added by me.

11.3.4 defines array declarations. Paragraph one contains

> If the constant-expression [between the square brackets] (8.20) is present, it shall be a **converted constant expression** of type std::size_t [...].

`std::size_t` is from `<cstddef>`and defined as

> [...] an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object.

Since it is imported via the C standard library headers the C standard is relevant for the properties of `size_t`. The ISO C draft [N2176](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) prescribes in 7.20.3 the "minimal maximums", if you want, of integer types. For `size_t` that maximum is 65535. In other words, a 16 bit `size_t` is entirely conformant.

A "converted constant expression" is defined in 8.20/4:

> A **converted constant expression** of type T is an expression, implicitly converted to type T, where the converted expression is a constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only [any of 10 distinct conversions, one of which concerns integers (par. 4.7):]
>
> — integral conversions (7.8) **other than narrowing conversions** (11.6.4)

An integral *conversion* (as opposed to a *promotion* which changes the type to equivalent or larger types) is defined as follows (7.8/3):

> A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of another integer type.

7.8/5 then excludes the integral *promotions* from the integral *conversions.* This means that the *conversions* are usually **narrowing** type changes.

*Narrowing conversions* (which, as you'll remember, are excluded from the list of allowed conversions in *converted constant expressions* used for array sizes) are defined in the context of list-initialization, 11.6.4, par. 7

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>   [...]
>   7.3<sup>1</sup> — from an integer type [...] to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, **except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type.**

This is effectively saying that the effective array size must be the constant value at display, which is an entirely reasonable requirement for avoiding surprises.

---

Now let's cobble it all together. The working hypothesis is that `std::size_t` is a 16 bit unsigned integer type with a value range of 0..65535. The integer literal `65537` is not representable in the system's 16 bit `unsigned int` and thus has type `long`. Therefore it will undergo an *integer conversion.* This will be a *narrowing conversion* because the value is not representable in the 16 bit `size_t`<sup>2</sup>, so that the exception condition in 11.6.4/7.3, "value fits anyway", does not apply.

So what does this mean?

11.6.4/3.11 is the catch-all rule for the failure to produce an initializer value from an item in an intializer list. Because the initializer-list rules are used for array sizes, we can assume that the catch-all for conversion failure applies to the array size constant:

> **(3.11) — Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.**

A conformant compiler is required to produce a diagnostic, which it does. Case closed.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Yes, they sub-divide paragraphs.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Converting an integer value of 65537 (in whatever type can hold the number — here probably a `long) to a 16 bit unsigned integer is a defined operation. 7.8/2 details:</sub>

> <sub>If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source
>   integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two’s
>   complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is
>   no truncation). —end note ]</sub>

<sub>The binary representation of 65537 is `1_0000_0000_0000_0001`, i.e. only the least significant bit of the lower 16 bits is set. The conversion to a 16 bit unsigned value (which circumstantial evidence indicates `size_t` is) computes the [expression value] modulo 2^16, i.e. simply takes the lower 16 bits. This results in the value of 1 mentioned in the compiler diagnostics.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

In your implementation `size_t` is defined as `unsigned int` and `uint32_t` is defined as a `long unsigned int`. When you create a C array the argument for the array size gets implicitly converted to `size_t` by the compiler.

This is why you're getting a warning. You're specifying the array size argument with an `uint32_t` that gets converted to `size_t` and these types don't match.

This is probably not what you want. Use `size_t` instead.

Comment: "size_t is defined as 'unsigned int'" - not necessarily

Comment: That's not what I said, I meant that in his case it is. @Bathsheba

Comment: "size_t is defined as 'unsigned int' and therefore 'uint32' ": **In your implementation!** That this is not always so is the very reason for the introduction of `size_t`.

Comment: Which is why I told him to use size_t
My first sentence describes the warning adn the second the solution.

Comment: @vlind please edit your post to remove ambiguities and you'll have the votes reversed

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yeah I wasn't being clear enough. is this better?

Comment: @vlind yes, please use `` backticks for the "code" words instead of `'`

Comment: This means that the OP's problem of allocating an array of 65537 bytes is not possible, because this exceeds the capacity of his size_t.

Comment: Minor niggle: `uint32` should be `uint32_t` of course.

Comment: Looks to me as if n4659 forbids narrowing conversions (the rules for initializer lists apply, 11.6.4) one of which is defined as "from an integer type [...] to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression **whose value after integral
promotions will fit into the target type**" (11.6.4/7.3). That the latter is not given is exactly the issue here, so the prog is actually ill-formed, would be my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

The value returned by `sizeof` will be of type `size_t`.

It is generally used as the number of elements in an array, because it will be of sufficient size. `size_t` is always unsigned but it is implementation-defined which type this is. Lastly, it is implementation-defined whether the implementation can support objects of even `SIZE_MAX` bytes... or even close to it.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer was written when the question was tagged with C and C++. I have not yet re-examined it in light of OP’s revelation they are using C++ rather than C.]

`size_t` is the type the C standard designates for working with object sizes. However, it is not a cure-all for getting sizes correct.

`size_t` should be defined in the `<stddef.h>` header (and also in other headers).

The C standard does not require that expressions for array sizes, when specified in declarations, have the type `size_t`, nor does it require that they fit in a `size_t`. It is not specified what a C implementation ought to do when it cannot satisfy a request for an array size, especially for variable length arrays.

In your code:

```
const uint32_t N = 65537;
uint8_t values[N];
```

`values` is declared as a variable length array. (Although we can see the value of `N` could easily be known at compile time, it does not fit C’s definition of a constant expression, so `uint8_t values[N];` qualifies as a declaration of a variable length array.) As you observed, GCC warns you that the 32-bit unsigned integer `N` is narrowed to a 16-bit unsigned integer. This warning is not required by the C standard; it is a courtesy provided by the compiler. More than that, the conversion is not required at all—since the C standard does not specify the type for an array dimension, the compiler could accept any integer expression here. So the fact that it has inserted an implicit conversion to the type it needs for array dimensions and warned you about it is a feature of the compiler, not of the C standard.

Consider what would happen if you wrote:

```
size_t N = 65537;
uint8_t values[N];
```

Now there would be no warning in `uint8_t values[N];`, as a 16-bit integer (the width of `size_t` in your C implementation) is being used where a 16-bit integer is needed. However, in this case, your compiler likely warns in `size_t N = 65537;`, since `65537` will have a 32-bit integer type, and a narrowing conversion is performed during the initialization of `N`.

However, the fact that you are using a variable length array suggests you may be computing array sizes at run-time, and this is only a simplified example. Possibly your actual code does not use constant sizes like this; it may calculate sizes during execution. For example, you might use:

```
size_t N = NumberOfGroups * ElementsPerGroup + Header;
```

In this case, there is a possibility that the wrong result will be calculated. If the variables all have type `size_t`, the result may easily wrap (effectively overflow the limits of the `size_t` type). In this case, the compiler will not give you any warning, because the values are all the same width; there is no narrowing conversion, just overflow.

**Therefore, using `size_t` is insufficient to guard against errors in array dimensions.**

An alternative is to use a type you expect to be wide enough for your calculations, perhaps `uint32_t`. Given `NumberOfGroups` and such as `uint32_t` types, then:

```
const uint32_t N = NumberOfGroups * ElementsPerGroup + Header;
```

will produce a correct value for `N`. Then you can test it at run-time to guard against errors:

```
if ((size_t) N != N)
    Report error…

uint8_t values[(size_t) N];
```

Comment: Hi Eric. Every size is known at compile time. What I am doing is simply `template <size_t N> struct MyArray{ uint8_t data[N]; }`. Now I am using `size_t`, but before I was using `uint32_t`. The exception mentioned comes from a unit test which stretches the boundaries.

Comment: @Fabio: The question is currently tagged as C. I see you entered it with C and C++ tags, and somebody other you removed the C++ tag. Templates are a C++ feature, so you need to clarify that the question is asking about C++. C and C++ are different languages, and answers for one may not be applicable to the other.

Comment: Thanks Eric. The question is a simplification of what I am doing. I believe that a static array declaration must be handled consistently by the compiler in C and C++, hence the simplification.