# Struct containing an array of struct cannot be allocated by values from a list of the same type

Tags: c, arrays, struct

My problem is the following: I have a structure called `Environment`, containing a list of `Obstacle` structures. I am not able to allocate this `environment.obstacles` from a existing list of `Obstacle` created manually in the code.

I have the following definitions:

```
struct PointGPS {
    double longitude;
    double latitude;
} typedef PointGPS;

struct Obstacle {
    int id;
    PointGPS position;
    double radius;
} typedef Obstacle;

struct Environment {
    Obstacle *obstacles;
    PointGPS destination;
} typedef Environment;
```

And I am using the following functions to instantiate my values:

```
PointGPS createPoint(double longitude, double latitude) {
    PointGPS point;
    point.latitude = latitude;
    point.longitude = longitude;
    return point;
}

Obstacle createObstacle(int id, double radius, PointGPS position) {
    Obstacle obstacle;
    obstacle.id = id;
    obstacle.radius = radius;
    obstacle.position = position;
    return obstacle;
}

Environment createEnvironment(PointGPS destination, Obstacle *obstacles) {
    Environment environment;
    environment.destination = destination;
    environment.obstacles = obstacles;
    return environment;
}
```

In my `main` function I am creating a list of obstacles:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NELEMS(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))

int main() {
    PointGPS pointGps1 = createPoint(49.202538, 6.918930);
    PointGPS pointGps2 = createPoint(49.202650, 6.925839);
    PointGPS destination = createPoint(49.202660, 6.925849);
    Obstacle obstacle1 = createObstacle(1, 10, pointGps1);
    Obstacle obstacle2 = createObstacle(2, 30, pointGps2);
    Obstacle *obstacles[2];
    obstacles[0] = &obstacle1;
    obstacles[1] = &obstacle2;
    // environment is global
    environment = createEnvironment(destination, *obstacles);
    // The two following methods allow me to print the id of the first element
    printf("%d\n", environment.obstacles->id);
    printf("%d\n", environment.obstacles[0].id);
    // But I cant access to the values -for exemple the id field- of the following obstacles
    printf("%d\n", environment.obstacles[1].id);
}
```

I want to give this list to my `environment`. But it fails allocating or pointing to the correct values. Testing by the `id` of some obstacles in `environment.obstacles` always returns some random integer values from the memory.

I tried the following attempts :

1)

```
// environment is global
environment = createEnvironment(destination, *obstacles);
```

2)

```
environment.obstacles = (Obstacle *)malloc(sizeof(Obstacle *) * NELEMS(obstacles));
environment.obstacles[0] = *obstacles[0];
environment.obstacles[1] = *obstacles[1];
```

3)

```
environment.obstacles = (Obstacle *)malloc(sizeof(Obstacle *) * NELEMS(obstacles));
environment.obstacles[0] = createObstacle(obstacles[0]->id, obstacles[0]->radius, createPoint(obstacles[0]->position.longitude, obstacles[0]->position.latitude));
environment.obstacles[1] = createObstacle(obstacles[1]->id, obstacles[1]->radius, 
createPoint(obstacles[1]->position.longitude, obstacles[1]->position.latitude));
```

All these attempts failed, returning values like `-2144113376`, and not even creating an array of length = 2 in my `environment` variable.

I am pretty sure I'm missing something obvious, as I have zero experience in this language, but I can't figure it out.
How could I proceed ?

**UPDATE 1**:

This syntax allowed me to access the first obstacle using the method n°1:

```
printf("%d\n", environment.obstacles->id)
```

But I can't access to the second obstacle. Doing `printf("%d\n", environment.obstacles[1]->id);` returns this error :

```
Member reference type 'Obstacle' (aka 'struct Obstacle') is not a pointer, did you mean to use '.'?
```

And doing `printf("%d\n", environment.obstacles[1].id);` still returns random values.

**UPDATE 2**:

As requested, i edited the structures, functions and main.

**UPDATE 3**:

Here is a testable code doing what is attempted in my post.
https://onlinegdb.com/S1342WPsN
If I run the code on my computer I still have random values as described when trying to access the fields following the first one.
But if I run the code inside the website (see link), it seems to provide the correct value.

Comment: A pointer is not an array

Comment: You could use either allocated memory to store the pointers, a linked list (probably what you want), or an array of pointers big enough to hold all the pointers you may need (only valid if you know a reasonable limit, but in that case it's the best option, as it doesn't involve allocating and therefore freeing memory).

Comment: What is `NELEMS`? What does `NELEMS(obstacles)` return?

Comment: @CacahueteFrito i updated the question, as i succedded in accessing the first element , but cannot access the second one. I will try the chained list and arry of pointers approach, but i wished there was a direct solution to the actual way i am doing things.

Comment: @KamilCuk 
```NELEMS``` is :
```#define NELEMS(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))```
it was meant to return the size of the array, but maybe this is wrong too .. !

Comment: @drheinrich940 `NELEMS(x)` is ok. Usually I've seen that macro called `ARRAY_SIZE(arr)`.  Just remember its return type is `size_t`, which is unsigned.  There's many times where you need a signed size, so you either cast, or have another macro to hide the cast (in my case `#define ARRAY_SSIZE(arr) ((ptrdiff_t)ARRAY_SIZE(arr))`

Comment: Please include all the relevant source files, the `PointGPS` definition, all the includes and `main()` functions. Please post an MCVE - reproducible example, that others can copy into sites like http://onlinegdb.com etc. There is much missing. I was not able to [reproduce](https://onlinegdb.com/Sy4SqlDi4) the behavior. The code you posted looks ok.

Comment: How did you get the results in your update? One of the three methods you had tried? (If so, which?)

Comment: @CacahueteFrito a simple ```(int)``` cast would not work ? I got the results with the first method introduced. I made some edits in the main post to clarify this.

Comment: @KamilCuk proceeded as you requested. You will find an MCVE - reproducible example at the end of my post in UPDATE 3. Sorry for the missing parts of code.

Comment: For most cases, yes, a cast to `(int)` will work. More: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3174900/6872717

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a confusion between arrays and pointers. `obstacles` in your `main` function is an array of pointers to `Obstacle` structures. You probably want to define an array of `Obstacle` structures, initialized with copies of `obstacle1` and `obstacle2`, and pass that to `createEnvironment`. Passing an array as an argument effectively passes a pointer to its first element.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NELEMS(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))

int main() {
    PointGPS pointGps1 = createPoint(49.202538, 6.918930);
    PointGPS pointGps2 = createPoint(49.202650, 6.925839);
    PointGPS destination = createPoint(49.202660, 6.925849);
    Obstacle obstacle1 = createObstacle(1, 10, pointGps1);
    Obstacle obstacle2 = createObstacle(2, 30, pointGps2);
    Obstacle obstacles[2];
    obstacles[0] = obstacle1;
    obstacles[1] = obstacle2;
    // environment is global
    environment = createEnvironment(destination, obstacles);
    // The two following methods allow me to print the id of the first element
    printf("%d\n", environment.obstacles->id);
    printf("%d\n", environment.obstacles[0].id);
    // This one should print the id of the second element
    printf("%d\n", environment.obstacles[1].id);
    return 0;
}
```

Note also that your `tyedef` definitions are not idiomatic in C. The `typedef` keyword usually comes first:

```
typedef struct PointGPS {
    double longitude;
    double latitude;
} PointGPS;
```

Comment: Note that this works because the array is created in main, and therefore it exists during all the program (almost `static`).  If it were created in a normal function, the array would be local to that function and it would disappear the moment the function returns.

Comment: IMHO, I would even separate the `typedef` into its own statement.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add pictures to the problem, this is what was defined in your code, (forgive my UML.)

[image: The data types.]

What you've done is created this.

[image: The data.]

Specifically, `*obstacles` is the same as `obstacles[0] = &obstacle1`.