# C - best way of structuring function signature In my example

Tags: c

I just started learning `C`, and it's completely new mindset to grasp for me, coming from `Swift`. I wanted to ask what is the best/most common approach to structure the signature of function in my particular example. I want to make a function, which scans local WiFi networks, and returns the list of them. It's all synchronous, let's just consider the type of values returned. For now I have this:

```
void wifi_client_scan(struct wifi_client* client, uint16_t max_results, wifi_ap_record_t* results, uint16_t *results_count);
```

What Im wondering is:

- Is this correct approach to pass pointer to array in this form (wifi_ap_record_t*) instead of function returning wifi_ap_record_t* and not void?
- Is returning the number of results in this form the right way to go? (pointer to uint16_t)
- Are there other things I should consider here?

Comment: You might as well make the function return a value, such as `results_count` (or <=0 to indicate error). And unless you have serious memory constraints, it's better to use the natural `int`.

Comment: Extending what WeatherVane said (re. using `int`): Believe it or not, using the natural size `int` (e.g. 32 bits) actually runs _faster_ on many CPU architectures (x86 in particular) than using a 16 bit `unsigned short`. If it were me, I'd do: `int wifi_client_scan(struct wifi_client *client, int max_results, wifi_ap_record_t *results) { int retcount = ...; if (err) retcount = -1; return retcount; }`

Comment: As for the type of uint16_t, this type is returned by the WiFi library Im using, hence the format. So you are saying to return the number of results as function result, and still pass the result to the array pointer? Could you explain why this approach? Is this some kind of standard?

Comment: in addition, I'd say it's hard to say without knowing more. Understand that every argument in C is pass by _value_, so copies of all the arguments are made when you call the function. You pass pointers to effectively pass by reference ... in your `wifi_client_scan` function, you can dereference `client`, `results`, and `results_count`, modify what they point to, and those changes will persist outside of the function. Any change you make to `max_results` will not. If that all tracks with what you need, then function signature looks fine to me. My apologies if you know all that already.

Comment: @yano I know nothing, and C is like completely new land to me, so every input is valid, thank you for it :)

Comment: If you like the answers, please consider accepting one of them. I will upvote your question if you make the title more specific (like, say that it involves an array and its array size) and confirm it to me.

Answer (score 3):

From your comment under LoverofStructure's answer:

> Thank you. As for the * I like to put in near the type, as I consider the value to be of type pointer to something. Im open to changing this approach if I find it more appropriate in the future. –
> Damian Dudycz

This is *not* canonical/idiomatic:

```
int* ptr;
```

That's because, in C, `*` is *tightly bound* to `ptr` and *not* `int`.

The idiomatic way is:

```
int *ptr;
```

When we have:

```
int* a,b;
```

This implies [incorrectly]:

```
int* a; // pointer
int* b; // pointer
```

Because of the binding, it actually translates to:

```
int *a; // pointer
int b; // value
```

So, we do:

```
int *a,b;
```

Or:

```
int *a,b,*c = &b;
```

To get:

```
int *a;
int b;
int *c = &b;
```

So, for uniformity, we do:

```
int *a;
```

Comment: "*tightly bound*" -> "*tightly bound* in terms of how C is parsed"

Comment: Thats a very good point, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

A safe choice for the type for array indexing in C is `size_t`, because it is guaranteed to be able to hold any possible array index. (As a commenter pointed out, the actual [best choice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3174850/2057969) will depend on your situation.) Of course, you are likely to need only a small integer type in your case.

As for how to designate arrays in a function signature, there are different styles:

- `wifi_ap_record_t* results` emphasizes the fact that *as formal parameters in a function definition*, `T arr[]` is equivalent to `T *arr`.
- `wifi_ap_record_t results[]` emphasizes that semantically you're dealing with an array instead of a pointer (assuming that you are in fact dealing with an array).

I'd therefore personally go with the following:

```
void wifi_client_scan(
  struct wifi_client *client,
  size_t max_results,
  wifi_ap_record_t *results,
  size_t *results_count) {
    …
}
```

This function signature keeps `results` and `results_count` alongside each other, but this isn't the only way one can do things.

Note that in a function prototype you don't need parameter names:

```
void wifi_client_scan(
  struct wifi_client *,
  size_t,
  wifi_ap_record_t *, size_t *);
```

There is debate about the spacing around the `*` within declarations; follow whichever style makes more sense to you.

Comment: Thank you. As for the * I like to put in near the type, as I consider the value to be of type pointer to something. Im open to changing this approach if I find it more appropriate in the future. As for the rest of your response I suppose I could replace wifi_ap_record_t* results  with wifi_ap_record_t results[] to let know that we are dealing with array right? I think it makes sense. Are there no other differences in using it like so?

Comment: *The best type to use for array indexing in C is `size_t`*  Citation needed.

Comment: Within function signatures, `T arr[]` and `T *arr` are 100% equivalent. But in general, arrays and pointers are not the same (unlike some people sometimes claim).

Comment: Using the unsigned  `size_t` for iterating an array downwards creates problems detecting the end of the loop.

Comment: @WeatherVane `while(size_t_variable--)`

Comment: @Damian *"I like to put in near the type"* ... bear in mind that `char* a, b` only defines one pointer variable. My own preference is `char *a, *b` then it's really clear.

Comment: @TedLyngmo fair enough: I was thinking of the `for` loop - do you have a way to do that?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks; I made a corresponding edit.

Comment: @WeatherVane I usually do the same there: `for(variable = x.size(); variable--;)`