# What is the unsigned counterpart of ptrdiff_t?

Tags: c++

What is the unsigned counterpart of `ptrdiff_t`?
And similarly - what is the signed counterpart of `size_t`?

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a unsigned type that I can use to store the positive values of `ptrdiff_t` variable without worrying about large values - this seems to be `size_t`.

Conversely - I would like to have a signed type that I can store the values of `size_t`, again without worrying about large values.

Comment: There's `intptr_t` Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464174/size-t-vs-intptr-t

Comment: @IronMensan Surely you mean `uintptr_t`! (u for unsigned)

Comment: Have you considered looking at the standard?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is a formal unsigned counterpart to `ptrdiff_t` (no `uptrdiff_t`), but using `size_t` for it is pretty reasonable.

In POSIX, the signed counterpart to `size_t` is `ssize_t`.  It is the type returned by functions such as [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html), for example.

That suggests there will be few implementations where the underlying type of `ssize_t` and `ptrdiff_t` will be different.

Answer (score 4):

`size_t` is used to represent object sizes. It was widely believed that compiler writers will not create objects with negative sizes.

Note that with ptrdiff_t` you get the difference depending on how you are comparing, so a signed type makes sense (changing this to a unsigned type for reasonable values is trivial):

> **5.7 Additive operators**
>
> **6** [...]As with any other arithmetic overflow, if the result does not fit in the space provided, the behavior is undefined.[...]

So, you may need to create a special type for 'very large values'.

Comment: By reading your answer, I would assume `ssize_t` does not exist.

Comment: @fontanini: in standard C, there is no type `ssize_t`; that is a POSIX extension to the C standard.

Comment: Oops, thought it was a standard definition. My bad :D