# Are uintptr_t and size_t same?

Tags: c++, types, casting, std

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [size_t vs. intptr_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464174/size-t-vs-intptr-t)

Some of my code deals with pointers and takes `uintptr_t` as input since it has to work with pointers.

I now have to do the same thing with integers, So I want to reuse that code.

Is `size_t` the same as `uintptr_t`? Can I change the implementation and use the same code for both pointers and integers just by replacing `uintptr_t` with `size_t`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`size_t` has to be big enough to contain the size of the largest
possible object.  `uintptr_t` must be big enough to contain
*any* pointer.  Given this, it is more or less guaranteed that
`sizeof(uintptr_t) >= sizeof(size_t)` (since all of the bytes in
the largest possible object must be addressable), but not more.
On machines with linear addressing, they probably will be the
same size.  On segmented architectures, on the other hand, it is
usual for `uintptr_t` to be bigger than `size_t`, since an
object must be in a single segment, but a pointer must be able
to address all of the memory.

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon the implementation (and that includes the processor, the ABI, the compiler, the standard libraries). You have no guarantee that `size_t` is the same as `uintptr_t`; but that could happen (on 32 bits Linux x86 or ARM, both are 32 bits unsigned integers).

And the intent of `size_t` is to be a size (notably of allocated memory chunks), while the intent of `uintptr_t` is to be an unsigned integer of the same bit size as pointers.

Answer (score -2):

Different compilers have different results. If you want them to be the same, you must make sure that your compiler is set to 32 bit Linux x86 or ARM, and then it will right.