# Correct usage of vector<int>::size_type

Tags: c++, c++11

I saw in some very well known books on C++ that --

```
vector<int> ivec;

for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
    ivec.push_back(i);
    ivec.push_back(i);  // duplicate copies of each number

}
```

I was wondering why `vector<int>::size_type` is used here. They are not
comparing `i` with size of the vector. Intent is to insert 10 `int`'s in the
vector, so `int i = 0` would be a right thing to do, isn't it ?

`vector<int>::size_type` would be `typedef` for `std::size_t` which in turn will
be `unsinged int`, but here we are storing `int`'s in the `vector`.

Please clarify my understanding about `vector<int>::size_type`. Is it fair to use it in the for loop above ?

Comment: Just use `ptrdiff_t` for the general case, e.g. named `Size`. That's a signed type, so that you avoid simple promotions introducing bugs in your code. Also you avoid the bug-attracting complexity of code that goes overboard in trying to use the `size_type` defines (IMHO the most silly aspect of blind conformance in modern C++ coding; it's all negative value cruft, perceived as the opposite).

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918567/size-t-vs-containersize-type

Comment: I would agree that `int` is a more natural choice here. However it is important that your loop does not cause an overflow.  If you wrote a similar loop but using `i != x` instead of `i != 10`, and `x` might be bigger than `INT_MAX` then you have to be careful.

Comment: In my opinion this is too pedantic, just use int as for day to day vectors you dont need 2GB vectors and in the rare case you find yourself needing it you are VERY aware of that need that you pay special attention anyway.

Comment: @ Pavan Manjunath I already went through this, my question is - is it fair to use it in the code ? I don't think it is fair, but I wanted to clarify (endorsement) for my understanding.

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen what do 2GB vectors have to do with this? Maybe you overlook that `i` is not used as a vector index

Comment: Well, the vector's `value_type` is `int` so it makes sense to use that for the loop variable. After all you're pushing `i` into the vector. I think some of the other commenters are answering a different question.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf you can flag it for containing nonsense and misleading info :P

Comment: yep, I deleted I remember seeing that and mind played a trick! But which well known book has this example I am curious!

Comment: Although it is common in practice for `std::vector<int>::size_type` to be `std::size_t`, that is neither required nor guaranteed.   Similarly, although `std::size_t` is the same as `unsigned int` for *some* implementations, there are also real-world implementations where `std::size_t` is a different type (albeit it is still an unsigned integral type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the above code is 'fine' in the sense that it compiles and does the intended job, as others have said.

When they said the intent was to insert ten `int`s in the vector, the `int`s are guaranteed positive because of how the loop is formatted, so the `unsigned int` will just convert into `int`.

However, I don't believe this is good practice as you said - the size type has nothing to do with the type of the elements being inserted - the size type is basically always an `unsigned int`. Just using `int` or `value_type` would obviously make the intent of the code clearer.

Comment: Which books use that loop anyway?

Comment: Interesting. I have that book and it seems that the authors probably do that out of customary 'tradition' as the size type will always hold the **largest** index a vector can have. Good code will never have overflows but I guess it is a precaution just in case an overflow actually happens. There's nothing wrong with doing this to be honest - just not needed most of the time when you're writing 'good' code.

Comment: And in this case, they're not even iterating through each element of the vector, just adding 10 values. Probably just habit.

Comment: Just a note: `size_t` is not the same as `unsigned int`: size_t depends of the memory address size `sizeof(void*)`, while unsigned int could be as small as 16bit. E.g. on a 8bit MCU, unsigned int will probably be 16bits, while the size_t could be 8bits.

Comment: Another Stack Overflow answerer believes it's not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18810800/is-sizeofsize-t-sizeofvoid-always-true
I think for most implementations, size_t is an unsigned int, but it is after all implementation-defined.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say no, this code is not correct and many compilers will warn about the implicit cast from `size_t` to `int`.

`vector::size_type`/`size_t` should always be used for vector indexes but if you have a `vector` of `int` then you should be inserting `int`s into it.

The correct code would be:

```
vector<int> ivec;

for (vector<int>::value_type i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
    ivec.push_back(i);
    ivec.push_back(i);  // duplicate copies of each number
}

for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < ivec.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << ivec[i] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Why do you say "is not correct"? It does what it should. Implicitly converting `size_t` to `int` in this case is well defined. If a compiler warn for this, it is because it doesn't analyse the code thoroughly enough. I'm not saying that this code is 100% beautiful, but calling it "not correct" is not the right word.

Comment: OK, in this case the numbers are 0-10 so there is no problems but in my experience compilers don't necessarily analyse the code that deeply and will warn about this code. In the general case the numbers might not be in the valid range of both types then subtle bugs will occur

Comment: If a larger number than `INT_MAX` is used in the for loop, then this code will have a real problem (yours and OP's version as well). But if the range is smaller, then everything is fine for both versions.

Comment: @geza apart from for negative numbers and assuming `size_t` is larger or the same size as `int` which isn't necessarily the case

Comment: If `size_t` is less than `int`, then still both versions have problems, as you cannot add more elements into a vector than `SIZE_MAX` (let's not consider negative numbers here, as the original example doesn't have them).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid implicit casts and compiler warnings you can be explicit about what you `push_back`:

```
vector<int> ivec;

for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
    ivec.push_back(static_cast<int>(i));
    ivec.push_back(static_cast<int>(i));
}
```

Using `size_type` and `static_cast` in this code seems to be artificial. It would be more meaningful in the following example (a combination of @AlanBirtles's examples):

```
vector<int> ivec(20);

for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
    ivec[2 * i] = ivec[2 * i + 1] = static_cast<int>(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### In general

Yes, your *value* type is `int`.

But that's not what `size_type` is talking about. `size_type` is the type of the *indices* of the vector. It's the type of the *size* of the vector (hence its name!).

We use a type alias for this (provided by the standard library) because it may/will differ across systems. It'll often be a `size_t`, which itself is a standard alias for some big unsigned type, albeit which one you cannot predict in general for a portable program.

---

#### But…!

This particular example is doubly confusing, because the book author really is populating vector *values* using the size type. This is not necessarily "wrong": in the range 0-9, it's not going to break. The compiler will just implicitly convert the integers in the usual way.

But it is expressing intent incorrectly.

I imagine it used to look like this:

```
vector<int> v(5);
for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
   v[i] = 42;
```

Then somebody has changed the loop body (such that `i` now is used for values, rather than for indices) and not thought about changing the loop preamble.

Making `i` an `int` would be far more clear and obvious.

Overall I'd consider avoiding these "well-known books" or, at least, checking their errata to see whether the code has been adjusted post-publication, because that's quite a strange example of C++.