# Is pointer just an integer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, integer

If I know the address of an data object, could I store the address as an integer and operate the integer as a pointer?

For example,

```
void main(){
    long a = 101010;
    long *p = &a;
    long b = p;
    printf("%lld\n", *(long*)b);
}
```

Is it always safe?

Comments: `long b = p;` produces a warning:

```
Initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

However, the program prints `101010`.

Comment: There is no such provision in the language standard that the pointer is always convertible to integer. It is just a coincidence, like int is for some reason long now.

Comment: this code should produce a warning about using a pointer as an integer without a cast.

Comment: if you had placed this code in a file and compiled it (with warnings enabled) the compiler would have flagged the code as incorrect.  Then there would have been no need to ask the question

Comment: Nothing is *always* safe; of course a pointer isn't *just* an `integer` but it is always representable as an `integer` (it might be an `int` or a `long` or even a 30-bit value but you could declare that is an `integer`).

Comment: In non-linear addressing architectures (such as x86 real mode), a pointer might not even be a single number. For example (again) in x86 real mode, a so-called "FAR" pointer is the composition of a segment address and an offset within the segment.

Comment: I don't understand. If pointer is not an integer(long or short or binary or whatever), what else could it be? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not guaranteed by the standard that such cast would always work.

To store a pointer in an integral type, use `intptr_t` (or its unsigned cousin `uintptr_t`). It's guaranteed to convert `void *` pointers to such types and convert back, resulting the same value.

Note that these types are optional.

Comment: They are normally the same as `ptrdiff_t` (signed) and `size_t` (unsigned), correct?

Comment: @technosaurus [Not really](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1464174/1009479). Note also that `ptrdiff_t` and `size_t` are not optional.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(long)` is typically defined by the compiler (subjected to the underlying HW architecture).

`sizeof(long*)` is subjected to the size of the virtual memory address space on your platform.

For example, with the Visual Studio compiler for 64-bit operating system and x64-based processor:

- `sizeof(long) == 4`
- `sizeof(long*) == 8`

Therefore:

- With `long b = p`, only the 4 least significant bytes of `p` are copied into `b`
- With `*(long*)b`, you are potentially attempting to access an invalid memory address

In this example, if the 4 most significant bytes of `p` are zero, then "no harm is done". But since it is not guaranteed to be the case, when `sizeof(long) != sizeof(long*)` this code is generally unsafe.

In addition to that, even if `sizeof(long) == sizeof(long*)`, you should still refrain from using this type of conversions (pointer-to-integer), in order to keep your code portable to other platforms.

---

**UPDATE**

Please note that `printf("%lld\n", *(long*)b)` is also unsafe.

You should basically use `"%ld"` for `long` values and `"%lld"` for `long long` values.

If `sizeof(long) < sizeof(long long)`, then it may lead to a memory access violation during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

To be on *safe* side, we should consider it's *not safe*.

Size of a pointer on a `n` bit system is `n` bits. For example, size of a pointer should be 8 byte on any 64-bit architecture / compiler. That's guranteed.

However, there is no such gurantee for data types. Its heavily compiler dependent. In your case, both just happens to have the same size, that's why it works.

---

EDIT:

For  the warning

```
Initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

Your compiler is very much right for producing the warning. Please check the data type. An `int *` variable is **not** equal to an `int` variable. In your case, it works just because there lengths are same in your particular case / implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Even `p` value and `b` value are same, only `p`  can access `a` i.e can to point `a`, `b` can not point to `a`. Because `p` is declared as pointer. `b` is declared as variable.

You cant access `a` through `b`. Then how is your question suitable. In `b`, address of `a` is treated as only `value` not a`address`, because of `b` is variable not a pointer..

Even it prints `101010`, this program is not a generic.

Answer (score -1):

A pointer is a variable whose value is the address of another variable. Like any variable or constant, you must declare a pointer before you can work with it. The general form of a pointer variable declaration is:

```
type *var-name;
```

The actual data type of the value of all pointers, whether integer, float, character, or otherwise, is the same, a long hexadecimal number that represents a memory address. The only difference between pointers of different data types is the data type of the variable or constant that the pointer points to.

**Pointers generally have a fixed size, for ex. on a 32-bit executable they're usually 32-bit. There are some exceptions, like on old 16-bit windows when you had to distinguish between 32-bit pointers and 16-bit... It's usually pretty safe to assume they're going to be uniform within a given executable on modern desktop OS's.**

Comment: It's so easy to do casting to a type that is guaranteed to be of the same size though...