# Using size_t for void pointer emulation

Tags: c, callback, type-conversion, void-pointers, size-t

```
int bar(const size_t value) {
  char *d = (char*) value; 
  *d = 'B';
}

int main() {
    char bar = 'A';
    bar((size_t)&d);
}
```

1. Is using `size_t` to emulate a void pointer type legal? Why?
2. What benefits/drawbacks does it have?

Comment: What do you mean by legal?

Comment: @reader `size_t` is being interpreted as `data*`, no? The function takes a parameter by value.

Comment: @gio:  You linked ***this*** question.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1464174/694576

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For *data* pointers, round trip from a pointer to an integer types back to the **original** pointer type is well defined as long as the integer type is wide enough to hold the pointer without loss.

`size_t` has been defined to hold object size.  They are usually big enough to hold  a pointer representation but that is not guaranteed and they were implementations where the assumption didn't hold.

`uintptr_t` and `intptr_t` are integer types defined to be wide enough to hold a pointer without loss.

For *function* pointers, I'm aware of no such guarantee.