# Why is it possible to cast integer types to pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, void, void-pointers

So, a void pointer is a generic pointer that can point to any of the chars or ints later, right? But it is, however, a pointer. However, this compiles without any error:

```
void* ptr; 
long var;
ptr = (void*)var;
```

Why is it possible here to typecast a `long` to a pointer? Shouldn't it give an error? Note that this also works if `var` was an `int` or `char`.

Also, the below snippet works if the `var` was `long`!

```
cout<<(long)ptr;
```

However, this doesn't work if `var` was an `int` or `char`. I don't know what to make of it. I am using 64 bit Linux machine.

Comment: It won't work on 64-bit platforms. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because a pointer is a numerical reference to a memory location, and thus can be cast as a numerical value.  In many cases, converting between them is much the same. For example, if I had a 32-bit memory location like `0x3E103A08` (pointers are usually viewed in hex form), that hex representation would be an unsigned integer equivalent of `1041250824`.  To get more detailed, a 32-bit pointer is just 4 bytes, and so is a 32-bit unsigned integer.  In fact, at the CPU level, CPU registers are used - some like pointers, and some for calculations - all of which (in my past developing in ASM) are more like integer variables under the hood.

Comment: The question doesn't mention or illustate "member pointer"s though - only `void*`s to non-member variables, but your basic point is right: memory addresses are just numbers, and if you ask the compile to assume there's an address in an integral variable, or move an address into one, why should it second guess you?

Comment: Sorry, my mind was split between something else I was writing.  I didn't mean member at all. ;) (typo)

Comment: The part about hex/dec is strange. It´s the same number. Your post sounds like hex is for pointers, decimal for `int`. (And no, pointers are not *generally* viewed in hex form.)

Comment: That's because most times pointers are viewed in hex form, not integer.

Answer (score 2):

It works, because pointers are in fact memory addresses, which in turn are represented by unsigned integer number (address).

Note, that `long` is usually 4-byte long, so it will not be able to hold memory address, if you switch to 64-bit platform (where pointers are 64-bit / 8 byte long). In this case, converting pointer to `int`/`long` will truncate (and thus, invalidate) its content.

To store address value, use `uintptr_t` (or signed version, `intptr_t`), as described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/):

> `intptr_t`, `uintptr_t`
>
> Integer type capable of holding a value converted from a void pointer and then be converted back to that type with a value that compares equal to the original pointer.
>
> **Optional:** These typedefs may not be defined in some library implementations.*

These types are optional, but available on most implementations. Even if they are not present, there should be platform-specific type defined for storing memory addresses.

Oh, and your point about conversions is not quite right - every integer (signed or unsigned) value can be converted to pointer (of any type, including `void*`) via explicit conversion. It also works the other way around.

Comment: `intptr_t` is standard in `<stdint.h>`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch **1.** Technically, there is no such thing like `<stdint.h>` in C++ (it is `<cstdint>`, which was linked in my answer). **2.** `<cstdint>` is a C++ 11 feature. **3.** [Documentation page for <cstdint> says, that both these types are optional](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/).

Comment: My mistake. I thought OP was talking of C, not C++

Comment: no, `long` is 8-byte long on most POSIX systems http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Read carefully. I wrote **usually** - MS Windows uses `LLP64` data model, which define `long` as 4-byte long. And since MS systems have ~90% usage share on desktop, that's what **usually** means to me.

Answer (score 0):

As a pointer contains addresses, and an address is a (integer-like) number, you *could* do this,
like you can cast `int` to `long` or `long` to `int`. The explicit cast tells the compiler that you´re aware of potential problems, so it won´t give you a warning.

However, it´s not guaranteed at all that a long can hold the same value range like a pointer,
so just don´t use `long`  for addresses.

Comment: if you would like to guarantee that `long var` can hold the same value range as the `void *` use `size_t var` instead

Comment: @portforwardpodcast Did you mean `intptr_t/uintptr_t`?

Comment: @portforwardpodcast No. `long` and `size_t` and `void*` are three different things.

Comment: ok @MohitJain I guess I misunderstood.  This post clears it up for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464174/size-t-vs-intptr-t

Comment: That's the beauty of this site, many confusions are cleared and things forgot can be remembered.