# ifort -> gfortran: INT_PTR_KIND()

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm porting some code from Intel Fortran to gfortran and I can not figure out how to port Intel's INT_PTR_KIND() function.

```
program main
  integer (INT_PTR_KIND()) v1
  integer v2

  print*, "sizeof v1:", sizeof(v1)
  print*, "sizeof v2:", sizeof(v2)   
  print*, "sizeof INT_PTR_KIND:", INT_PTR_KIND() 
end program main
```

gives me with Intel compiler following:

```
sizeof v1:                     8  
sizeof v2:                     4 
sizeof INT_PTR_KIND:           8
```

Please, how can I achieve following results in gfortran? I have tried with kind(1), sizeof,...everything gives me 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct integer kind from the `iso_c_binding` module for this is `c_intptr_t`

i.e. the most direct equivalent of your code is:

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding

integer(c_intptr_t) :: v1
```

`integer(8)` can mean anything or nothing at all for some compilers.

The `integer(c_intptr_t)` is directly interoperable with `intptr_t` from C ([size_t vs. uintptr_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464174/size-t-vs-intptr-t)).

Comment: problem is that on my 64arch c_intptr_t returns 4 and INT_PTR_KIND() 8

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling in 64 bit mode? They must show the same, otherwise it is a very serious bug. How EXACTLY are you inquiring that?

Comment: @fjordrunner If you do `sizeof(c_intptr_t)` then you are doing it wrong. You must do `sizeof(1_c_intptr_t)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the interoperability stuff, `use iso_c_binding`, in there, there is a special type for C pointers that is possibly what you are looking for.

```
program test
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none

    type(c_ptr) :: adr
    integer(8) :: int8
    integer :: int_default

    print*, sizeof(adr)
    print*, sizeof(int8)
    print*, sizeof(int_default)

end program test
```

follow [this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Working-with-Pointers.html) for more.

Comment: On my 64arch the output is 8,8,4. I assume that on 32arch the result will be 4,8,4? Correct?

Comment: I think so. For most 32arch, it will be 4, 8 4 as you suggested. But in the general case of 32arch, I have no certitude since some 32 bits system have implemented some trick to support more that 32 bits address, I do not know if it will hold for those systems.