# Dereferencing a pointer to size_t, but cast from void pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, event-handling, sdl, dereference

Basically, I'm pushing a user generated event onto an SDL event queue. In doing this, I push the address of an integer onto a void pointer which is the data1 parameter of SDL_PushEvent().

Later, I attempt to dereference the void pointer in the event fetched from the queue. When I do so, however, the value I'm supposed to get(1002) is nowhere near the value I actually do get: 140733847900856.

I was originally converting from a void pointer to an integer pointer. Alas, I'm on a 64-bit architecture, so I had to use size_t. But I'm not entirely familiar with size_t usage, so I'm probably doing something wrong.

Here's the code snippets, from two different source files:

from "splash.cpp":

```
  if(elapsed >= 13000 && !(flag)){
    std::cerr << "13 seconds elapsed.\n";

    // Create and push a CHANGE_GAME_MODE event to the queue.
    SDL_Event tmp;
    size_t data1 = MAIN_MENU_MODE;

    tmp.type=SDL_USEREVENT;
    tmp.user.code= CHANGE_GAME_MODE;
    tmp.user.data1 = &data1;
    tmp.user.data2 = NULL; // Not used.

    std::cerr << "Value of data1 before SDL_PushEvent():"
              << *((size_t*)(tmp.user.data1)) << "\n";

    SDL_PushEvent(&tmp);
    flag = true;
  }
```

from events.cpp:

```
  case SDL_USEREVENT:
    std::cerr << "\nUser event detected: " << *((size_t*)(event->user.data1)) << "\n";
    user_event(event->user.type, event->user.code, event->user.data1, event->user.data2);
    break;
```

Here are the results from cerr when I actually run the program:

```
sysadm@druid: ./kolodruidtale 
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
13 seconds elapsed.
Value of data1 before SDL_PushEvent():1002

User event detected: 140688563309902
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
```

(Note: I'm aware of what is causing the buffer underrun, and how to fix it. I want to get this dereferencing issue fixed first, though, so no worries. :D)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You really should use `std::intptr_t` instead of `std::size_t`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464174/size-t-vs-intptr-t.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `splash.cpp` you define a new variable `size_t data1 = MAIN_MENU_MODE;` that is allocated on the stack. Then you store its address to `tmp.user.data1`. When `size_t data1` goes out of scope in `splash.cpp` it gets automatically deleted.

When `event->user.data1` is dereferenced in `events.cpp` you get whatever happens to be in this address on the stack at that moment. This pointer is called a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) and dereferencing results in undefined behaviour. In your case you get a "random" number as a result. Normally, you get a segmentation fault.

You probably want to allocate this variable on the heap for what you are trying to do e.g.

```
size_t *data1 = new size_t(MAIN_MENU_MODE);
```

and remember to delete it when you no longer need it!

Comment: Ah, there it was! Thank you very, very much, Manos Nikolaidis! This makes me very happy. (^.^)

Answer (score 0):

Your `data1`, which is the object whose *address* you are storing in tmp.user.data1 *is local to the if*.

Therefore it will be destroyed upon exiting the block, and you will be left with a dangling pointer.

You might want to allocate your `data1` on the heap instead, using `new`.