# don't quite get what is: uintptr_t value(astruct.val)

Tags: c++, templates

I found the following syntax in a c++ source file (not header):

```
template <typename Type_> static void aFunction(Type_ &function, ...) {
    uintptr_t value(astruct.val); //confusing
}
```

Is that confusing line in question a declaration for value? I tried writing a hello world program like:

```
int main(){ uintptr_t a(80); return 0;}
```

and it returns an expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant, may i know what does that confusing line do? Thanks!

Edit: I think i should reveal the full function declaration:

```
    template <typename Type_>
static void nlset(Type_ &function, struct nlist *nl, size_t index) {
    struct nlist &name(nl[index]);
    uintptr_t value(name.n_value);// this is the confusing line
    if ((name.n_desc & N_ARM_THUMB_DEF) != 0)
        value |= 0x00000001;
    function = reinterpret_cast<Type_>(value);
}
```

Comment: What was the error? And where did `astruct` come from and what is its type?

Comment: What did you expect would happen? Your code would print hello world?

Comment: A `uintptr_t` is defined as an unsigned integer that is guaranteed to have the same size as an pointer. Did you forget to include `<stdint.h>` (C++03)?

Comment: The error i got was "expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant." I was expecting a to be initialised to 80 or sth..

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is uintptr_t data type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845482/what-is-uintptr-t-data-type)

Comment: i'm quite aware of what is uintptr_t datatype, but i'm not sure what value() does or is.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uintptr_t is an unsigned integer (at least) the size of a pointer.

It is not a native type though and you need to include `<stdint.h>` or `<cstdint>`

Really it is "evil" to cast pointers to ints and store them as integral variables but there is a lot of "legacy" code that does it and relies on it, and so you need an int size big enough to store it.

Storing them as integers allows you to do things you can do with ints "safely" but not with pointers, such as compare them when they are not part of the same range, in order to use them in memory-leak checkers, etc.

Comment: uintptr_t is an unsigned integer memsize-type that can safely store a pointer regardless of the platform capacity. The type uintptr_t is similar to the types size_t and UINT_PTR. The size of the type depends upon the data model.

Comment: according to what standard, steveoh? uintptr_t is not a C++ standard type.

Answer (score 2):

As you seem to know, `std::uintptr_t` is a standard type from the header `<cstdint>` (since C++11).

The line you don't understand is a simple variable declaration + definition:

```
uintptr_t value(name.n_value);
```

This declares a variable named `value` of type `uintptr_t` and initializes it with the value of `name.n_value`.  For fundamental types, this is equivalent to:

```
uintptr_t value = name.n_value;
```

---

> I tried writing a hello world program like:
>
> ```
> int main(){ uintptr_t a(80); return 0;}
> ```
>
> and it returns an error [...]

What error?  Always post the error message you are getting, nobody can help you with "I got an error"!

I suspect the error you are getting is caused by the fact that `uintptr_t` is not defined unless you include `<cstdint>`, and then you should use the `std` namespace prefix.

Comment: thanks for replying, but the error i got was:
expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant

Comment: Ok, i got it, Ferdinand was right, but on top of that, I used a gcc instead of g++ to compile my simple program. Thanks for the replies! I wonder why is the c compiler throwing up at the same int a(80); syntax..

Comment: @LeeWangHao: Constructor-style initialization is a C++ feature and not valid C, hence you get an error when using a C compiler.