# implementation of memcpy function

Tags: c, memcpy

I looked at 
    http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2050.24.15/libsyscall/wrappers/memcpy.c

and didn't understand the following :

1-

inside

```
void * memcpy(void *dst0, const void *src0, size_t length) {
    char *dst = dst0;
    const char *src = src0;
```

line:

```
if ((unsigned long)dst < (unsigned long)src) {
```

How can we cast dst to an unsigned long ? it's a pointer !

2- Why do they sometimes prefer forward copying and sometimes backwards??

Comment: Probably because the creator of the function knows that on the XNU platform, the type `unsigned long` is the same size as a pointer? There probably are some static assertions elsewhere that makes sure this is the case.

Comment: To have the quality of this question enhanced it would be nice to have the declarations of `dst` and `src` in place. This way the question would be clear without having to follow the link provided (which however could change over time).

Comment: @alk Good idea. I added it to the question.

Comment: pointer is an address, address can be represented as unsigned long

Comment: The forward/backward issue is because of possible overlap of the memory locations.

Comment: @zoska This isn't back by the C Standard, I suppose.

Comment: I wonder why the casts are in place at all? This should work perfectly fine the same way without casting the pointers to `unsigned long`.

Comment: IIUC this specific memcpy() is part of the syscall implementation, not of the standard library. There might be specific reasons to limit the pointers to a certain range of values, or perform other trickery on them (maybe the syscall has to translate them to a special range / address window) But it could just as well be caused by sloppy programming, of course.

Comment: @alk - you will get the compiler complaining if you compare "incompatible pointers". The cleanest way to code this, in my mind, would be `if((void*)dst < (void*)src)`. No need to know how big the pointers are, no compiler complaints (any pointer can be cast to `void *`).

Answer (score 4):

You are right, this implementation is non-portable, because it is assuming that a pointer is going to fit in `unsigned long`. This is not guaranteed by the standard.

A proper type for this implementation would have been [`uintptr_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1845482/335858), which is guaranteed to fit a pointer.

Comment: Note that `uintptr_t` is found in stdint.h and requires a somewhat modern C compiler (C99 or later).

Comment: Strangely, that same function later does cast the pointers to `uintptr_t`.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing a `void*` and `char*` pointer, the compiler will give a warning (`gcc -Wall`):

```
warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast
```

I imagine that the developer decided to "make the warning go away" - but the correct way to do this is with a `void*` cast (which is portable):

```
if((void*) dst < (void*) src) {
```

As for the second point - as was pointed out, you have to take care of overlapping memory locations. Imagine the following 8 characters in successive memory locations:

```
 abcdefgh
```

Now we want to copy this "3 to the right". Starting with a, we would get (with left-to-right copy):

```
abcdefgh
abcaefgh
   ^
abcabfgh
   ^^
abcabcgh
   ^^^
```

etc until you end up with

```
abcabcabcab
   ^^^^^^^^
```

When we wanted to get

abcabcdefgh

Starting from the other end, we don't overwrite things we still have to copy. When the destination is to the left of the source, you have to do it in the opposite direction. And when there is no overlap between source and destination, it doesn't matter what you do.