# Please explain what is incorrect about this procedure to find the largest pointer

Tags: c++

Wouldn't the highest pointer be the one which can't be incremented through pointer arithmetic?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    // Find the largest pointer
    int x = 0;
    int* px = &x;
    while ((px+1) != px)
      ++px;
    std::cout << "The largest pointer is: " << px;

    return 0;
}
```

yields

```
Timeout
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish, and where is the `Timeout` coming from?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "largest pointer"? The one with the highest address? What does it point to?

Comment: I think that you messed into the problems with operators significance order.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. Simple as that.

Comment: Will `while((px+1) != px)` ever terminate?  Ask yourself if the boolean expression `X + 1 == X` will ever be true.

Comment: Wouldn't int * px = (int *) (~0);  be a quicker way to accomplish this (rather dubious) task?

Answer (score 7):

As already mentioned, you've got an infinite loop because the condition can never be `false`.

That being said, what you're doing is undefined behaviour, illegal C++. Pointer arithmetic is only legal with pointers pointing to the same array (and a single object is treated as an array of one element) and right past the end of it. You can't expect a reasonable outcome of your program even if you fix the loop.

I suspect the value of [`std::numeric_limits`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845482/what-is-uintptr-t-data-type)`<`[`uintptr_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845482/what-is-uintptr-t-data-type)`>::max()` is the theoretical maximum value of pointer (converted to integer), but it might not be avaliable to your program. There are things such as [virtual address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) and [segmented memory model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation) to consider. Anyway, exact values of pointers (except for `nullptr`) is not something you should be concerned with. You get pointers by taking addresses of existing objects or by calling allocation functions and that's that.

N.B. I think you have a misconception that attempting to increment an integer type beyond its maximum value will just do nothing. That's incorrect - unsigned integers will wrap around to 0 and with signed integers you get undefined behaviour again (see [signed integer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is)).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

This will never be false and thus never quit

```
while ((px+1) != px)
```

Comment: I hate it when my cat jumps on my notebook while I try to write an answer. Sigh. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int *px = (int *) (~0);
  std::cout << "Value: " << px;
  ++px;
  std::cout << " Value: " << px << std::endl;  
}
```

whose output is:

```
Value: 0xffffffffffffffff Value: 0x3
```

As you can see, when you increment a pointer that is at its maximum, it values is reseted and begins again

Comment: ...but you can't rely on that with signed integers (it's undefined behaviour).

Comment: @Cameron: It's also not defined for pointers. If p were cast to a uintptr_t and that one being incremented it made kind of weird sense. But that way... nope.

Comment: @datenwolf: Oops, read the code too quickly. That's what I meant :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look for the largest pointer value that occurs before wrap-around, i.e.:

```
while (px+1 > px)
    px++;
```

...which will not work, of course, without the proper casts:

```
while ((unsigned long long)(px + 1) > (unsigned long long)px)
    px++;
```