# Trying to cast integer to void to pass to pthread function by value

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads, typecasting-operator

I am trying (using pthread_create) to pass a value to the function:

```
void philosopher(int);
```

I only need a way to differentiate between each thread. It does not matter which order they run in (clearly, since they are threads), nor even which order they were created in, but they need to contain a least one difference so that I can tell the difference between them. The reason for this is that, in the function, each thread needs to refer to itself as "philosopher 1, philosopher 2,...". The number of philosophers is dynamic (the user passes it as an argument when running the program).

```
pthread_t threads[philo];

for (int i = 0; i < philo; i++)
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &philosopher, reinterpret_cast<void*>(i));
```

I get an error from the above code: "invalid conversion from ‘`void (*)(int)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)`’ [-fpermissive]. Clearly, I need to pass i by value (because i changes in the for loop). I am stuck at compile time, however, and have only ever been able to have my pthread programs compile when the last value was NULL. I have also tried:

```
pthread_create(&threads[i],  NULL,  &philosopher,  i);
```

and

```
pthread_create(&threads[i],  NULL,  &philosopher,  (void*)i);
```

both of which produce the same compiler errors.

Comment: Does your compiler support C++11 threads? It's a lot easier to use threads with C++11.

Comment: How can I check this? I have the gnu compiler in the fedora rpm repository.

Comment: If `philo` is dynamic, then your code is not valid C++.

Comment: the thread routine must have the prototype `extern "C" void* philosopher(void*)`.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Good point, may I steal that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. You need a function of type `void * (void *)`, and you have a function of type `void (int)`. Fix it:

```
extern "C"
void * philosopher(void * data)
{
    uintptr_t n = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(data);

    // ...

    return nullptr;
}
```

(As @Deduplicator mentioned, strictly speaking `pthread_create` requires that the thread function have C linkage, so in C++ you need to declare it as `extern "C"`.)

Comment: What is the uintptr_t type? It is not recognized by my compiler.

Comment: @jaredad7: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1845482/596781). You need to include appropriate headers.

Comment: Ok, it is compiling fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You're having problem with a different parameter than you think - it's the thread function that's the problem.

It's supposed to take a `void *` - not an `int` - and return a `void *`, so change it to

```
void* philosopher(void*);
```

and inside the `philosopher` function, you cast the parameter back to an `int`.

(Don't cast the function - that's undefined.)