# function pointer bit shift

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have the following code:

```
void (* point)();
point=prova;
unsigned long int imm8 = point<<24;

...
void prova(){
...
}
```

The third line of code I have error:

> invalid operands to binary << (have 'void (*)()' and 'int')

I'm trying to apply the shift operator to a function pointer, but I get the following error. how can I do?

Comment: Why would you want to bit shift a pointer to a function?

Comment: You cannot bit shift a pointer. It doesn't even make sense. If you must live dangerous, cast the pointer to `uintptr_t`.

Comment: Clearly you don't fully understand what you are attempting here. Now is the time for you to explain your motivation for asking the question.

Comment: @pask I agree with the others. Although I have provided a working solution, you still need to say **why** you're doing what you're doing. Although there seems to be a troll here downvoting all actual answers, you still need to declare what exactly you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I have to concur that editing your question to explain your goal would help.

Comment: @C.R.: The language doesn't guarantee that you can convert a function pointer to `uintptr_t` without loss of information. That guarantee applies only to `void*` (and implicitly for other object pointer types, but function pointers can have a completely different representation). It will typically work, but it's not guaranteed. (And it's a very silly thing to do anyway.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: OK, then `uintmax_t`.

Comment: @C.R.: No, there's no guarantee that `uintmax_t`, or *any* integer type, is big enough to hold a converted pointer without loss of information. (I have yet to see an implementation where it isn't, though.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you want to do this but the error is correct, the draft C++ standard in section `5.8` *Shift operators* says;

> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed.[...]

You can use [reinterpret_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) to convert it to an integral type([uintptr_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845482/what-is-uintptr-t-data-type)) if needed. The linked reference contains the following example:

```
int i = 7;

// pointer to integer and back
uintptr_t v1 = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&i); // static_cast is an error
```

**Warning**

This type of conversion is only conditionally supported, we can see this from the C++ draft standard section `5.2.10` *Reinterpret cast* which says:

> Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa
>   is conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is
>   implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports
>   conversions in both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to
>   the other type and back, possibly with different cv- qualification,
>   shall yield the original pointer value.

Comment: There's no guarantee that you can convert a function pointer to `uintptr_t` without loss of information. (There is such a guarantee for `void*`.)

Comment: @KeithThompson thank you for that comment, I see now that it is conditionally supported. Let me add the standard quote.

Answer (score 2):

There is no portable way to do this.

The standard guarantees that you can convert a `void*` to `uintptr_t` without loss of information -- but it doesn't guarantee that `uintptr_t` exists. A conforming implementation might not have an integer type wide enough to hold a converted pointer without loss of information.

And even if `uintptr_t` exists, the language only guarantees that you can convert `void*` to `uintptr_t` without loss of information. A conforming permission might have, for example, 64-bit object pointers, 64-bit `uintprt_t`, and 128-bit function pointers.

It's likely, in most implementations, that you *can* convert a function pointer to `uintptr_t` without loss of information. (I think POSIX guarantees this, though the ISO C and C++ standards do not.)

Once you've done that, probably using a `reinterpret_cast`, you have an unsigned integer, which you can shift as you like.

The result of this shift will almost certainly be meaningless garbage. C++ doesn't prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot, which is what you appear to be trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no *valid* reason for doing this. However, you can do this by first casting to `unsigned long int`

```
unsigned long int imm8 = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long int >(point)<<24;
```

Here `reinterpret_cast` is done to *treat the pointer as `unsigned long int`*. Note that it is not portable and has the possibility of data loss.

Comment: How do you know an `unsigned long int` can hold a converted function pointer without loss of information?

Comment: @pask, each answer is about c++. However in `C` you can just cast to appropriate type `unsigned long int imm8 = (unsigned long int)point<<24;`. But as with C++, anything can happen

Comment: @pask if you have C source, why on earth did you tag this C++?