# stringstream converts unsigned long to formatted numeric string with commas

Tags: c++, stringstream

here's my code:

```
unsigned long a_ptr = *(unsigned long*)agent.m_ptr;
std::string a_type = agTypeToText(agent.GetType());
std::string a_cat = agCategoryToText(agent.GetCategory());

std::stringstream selInfo;
selInfo << "Agent pointer: " << a_ptr << "\nAgent type: " << a_type << "\nAgent category: " << a_cat;
```

when I display this, a_ptr looks like 834,993,193

when in reality i want it to display as a hexadecimal number, something like 0xFACEF00D, with or without the 0x. is there any way I can do this with stringstream?

Comment: have a look at [uintptr_t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845482/what-is-uintptr-t-data-type)

Answer (score 1):

Yes by passing [`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) to your `stringstream`

```
std::stringstream ss;
unsigned long v = 12345678910;
ss << std::hex << v;
std::cout << ss.str() << '\n';
```

or if you prefer uppercase digits

```
ss << std::uppercase << std::hex << v;
```

Comment: yes, i thought so. however while it now shows the proper hex characters, they are still comma separated.

Comment: Not for me. How are you printing the string?

Comment: `font.Draw(312, 7, 0xffffffff, selInfo.str());`

where `font.Draw` is defined as:
`void Font::Draw(float x, float y, DWORD color, std::string format, ...) const`

Comment: i figured it out - it was due to the addition of this: `locale::global(locale("en-US"));`

embarassing.