# Argument of type uint64_t is incompatible with parameter of type void*

Tags: c, arm

I have a function foo(void* pBuf). I need to pass it a 64 bit address but I can't seem to get the right typecast when I'm passing by value.

Example: foo(address). Where- uint64_t address=0x00000000DEADBEEF

EDIT: Compiling using an ARM compiler.

```
uint64_t foo(void *pBuf){
    uint64_t retAddr = (uint64_t) pBuf;
    retAddr += 0x100000;
    return retAddr;
}
```

I'm on a 32-bit ARM and `sizeof(void *)` is `4`

Clarification: Why I needed a 64-bit address on a 32-bit ARM?
Because my memory map uses 36-bit addressing.

Comment: address is a local variable which contains the address I need.

Comment: You will need to give more details about what sort of system you are on and what the `foo` function does with its argument

Comment: What's the problem in your latest code example ?
The only issue I can guess is that some compilers will issue warnings by casting directly from `void*` to `uint64_t`. In such a case, prefer a double cast : `(uint64_t)(size_t)`

Comment: The problem is in compiling the call to foo. Not the function itself.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the `address` did not start with `00000000` ? (bearing in mind that you are trying to fit the address into a 32-bit `void *`)

Comment: Then the address would be truncated and behave badly. My intention is that the input to foo is always 32-bit(in a 64 bit variable) and the returned value will be 64-bit.

Comment: In that case, `foo( (void *)(uint32_t)address );` would be correct. If your compiler rejects that then something is wrong with your compiler, or you made a typo

Comment: Yeah, this works. Your question led me to the solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two ways to get this right. Got a solution to my problem by calling foo the first way

1. foo((void*)(uint32_t)address)

This works only because my input to foo is always a 32-bit value. The returned value can be 64-bit.

2. Of course, a proper fix would be to change foo itself, if I could modify it.
   I could just pass foo(&address). Inside foo, retAddr = *pBuf.

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Call it this way:

```
uint64_t address = 0xDEADBEEF;
foo((void*)address);
```

That is, you *cast* the address to a void-pointer to be compatible with the function signature.

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour on systems with 32-bit `void *`

Comment: @M.M: That's irrelevant, because the OP already said they have a 64-bit address.  32-bit systems do not have 64-bit addresses.

Comment: @coder_mario: When you say "doesn't work" what does that mean?

Comment: I get this. Error:  #171-D: invalid type conversion

Comment: @coder_mario can you investigate as to what `sizeof(void *)` gives on your system?

Comment: 4 bytes. Sorry for the confusion. I'm on a 32-bit ARM.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to necro this question, but none of these answers seem reasonable to me. This is a fairly straightforward type conversion problem. It seems as though people were caught up on 64-bit addressing on a 32-bit system, when this could easily be for a peripheral or some other address space besides the system itself.

In the OP's case, a cast directly to `uint64_t` would cause undefined behavior because of the additional four bytes that do not exist in `void *`. In the case of the M4 calling convention, `p` would typically be passed in a single register, likely `r0`. There are no additional upper bytes for `uint64_t` to alias, so your compiler is rightly issuing a warning for this.

Under the GCC 7.3 `arm-none-eabi` port, `void *` can be safely cast to `size_t` (aka `unsigned int`) because they both have size and alignment of `4`. Once that is done, you can safely promote `unsigned int` to `uint64_t` (aka `unsigned long long int`) by assignment. The promotion is better defined behavior than a cast.

```
uint64_t foo(void *p){
    uint64_t a = (size_t) p;
    a += 0x100000;
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a 64-bits type for an address, as it is undefined behavior for 32-bits (or any non-64 bits) systems.

Rather, prefer using `uintptr_t`, which is standard C.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845482/what-is-uintptr-t-data-type) for more details or [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/) for references.

Then a solution could be :

```
uintptr_t address = 0xDEADBEEF;   /* will trigger a warning if the constant is > max possible memory size */
foo((void*)address);
```

Note : if `uintptr_t` is not available on your system, `size_t` is usually a good second choice.

Part 2 :

Looks like, in your rephrased question, you want to convert an address into a 64-bits integer.

In which case, a direct cast from ptr to integer is likely to trigger a compiler warning, due to potential differences in wideness.

Prefer a double cast :
`uint64_t value = (uint64_t)(size_t) ptr;`

Comment: I do need the 64 bit address though for AXI addressing