# Tagged Pointers for lockFree list in C

Tags: c++, pointers, bitmask, lock-free

I am trying to use tagged pointers for handling the lock free operations on a list, in order to block the compare-and-swap (CAS) from going through if some other thread operated on the list during this transaction. My node struct and CAS look like this:

```
struct node {
    unsigned long key;
    unsigned long val;
    struct node * next;
};

static inline bool CAS(std::atomic<node*> node, struct node* oldNode, struct node* newNode)
{
    node.compare_exchange_strong(oldNode, newNode, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}
```

I found some methods for setting and checking these pointers but it is unclear to me how they work, these are the methods for setting the mask and verifying it.

```
__inline struct node* setTagMask(struct node* p, int MASK_BIT)
{
    return (struct node*) ((uintptr_t)p | MASK_BIT);
}

__inline bool isMaskFlagSet(struct node* p)
{
    return ((uintptr_t)p & MASK_BIT) != 0;
}
```

So what is unclear to me is for example in the setTagMask, if I use it on my list than it will delete all its references to its value and next element as well.

Can anyone explain to me how can I properly set these bits so the other elements of the list remain the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setTagMask` function returns a modified version of the pointer `p`. If you store this modified pointer in your linked-list, then the list gets broken because the modified pointer does not point to a `node` anymore.

The pointer is modified as follows. The pointer `p` is converted to an unsigned integer which is capable to store a pointer: [`uintptr_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845482/what-is-uintptr-t-data-type).
Then one or more bits are set according to `MASK_BIT`. Finally, the result is converted back to a pointer and returned.

The function `isMaskFlagSet` checks whether the mask bits are still set.

The only use case, I can image is: you have to call `isMaskFlagSet` every time, before you use the pointer. If the mask bits are set, then it is prohibited to actually use the pointer.

Comment: But actually what I wanted to do is, modify one or two bits based on some scenarios, so I would know if any operations are done on these nodes in a different thread. Also this should block the CAS in case another thread works on the node, because the expected and the actual value won't match because of those bits.

Comment: Then you have to extend your `struct node` to include such a bit field, e.g. a "do not touch field". And this field should then be modified with CAS. You shouldn't modify the pointer.

Comment: @MartinZabel I think he is referring to something else: he wants to set the unused bits in the pointer address in order to CAS two node pointers. Indeed, how can this be done? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @TamasIonut Maybe I don't get it. You can't rely on unused bits in a pointer. This is purely implementation / platform dependent.

Comment: On x86/x64 architectures you have some unused bits (3 unused bits or x86 and 5 unused bits on x64, if I remember correctly). This is more broadly described: https://nikic.github.io/2012/02/02/Pointer-magic-for-efficient-dynamic-value-representations.html. So, indeed I am assuming some platform-specific risks since I will target x86/x64. But I still haven't managed to set the pointer address bits correctly either nor the OP.