# How to to set/get the low bits of a pointer to a struct?

Tags: c++, pointers, lock-free, stdatomic

I am trying to work on a lockfree solution for a self organizing list. I recently found out about the tagged pointers and thought it could work for me.

I have my node structure as follows:

```
typedef struct node {
  unsigned long val;
  struct node * next;
} node_t;
```

And I want to use on this the compare_exchange_strong function from the atomic library

```
std::atomic<node_t*> nodeAtomic;
nodeAtomic.store(node, std::memory_order_seq_cst);

nodeAtomic.compare_exchange_strong(nodeNew, node,    std::memory_order_seq_cst)
```

and for example if a thread is working on a node the cas should not go through because this lower bit will not match.

My questions are:

1. How can I set this bit without losing the references that the node has (next & val)?
2. How can I set it back?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845482/what-is-uintptr-t-data-type

Comment: Even if you could do this, it won't offer any benefit for you.  Tagged pointers operate on a per-pointer-variable basis.  If one thread uses one pointer variable to access a node, and uses that variable's bits to implement locking, another thread could use a completely different pointer variable to access the same node and bypass the lock.  The lock would only work if both threads share the same pointer variable.

Comment: I think he is indeed referring to a shared pointer variable and he just wants to be able to set the unused bits in a pointer for the CAS operation.