# printf format specifier flags '0' for %p, correct or not?

Tags: c++, printf, gcc-warning

Is appending '0' as flag to `printf` %p format specifier correct or not?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 42;
    void* p = &a;
    printf("Pointer address: %08p", p);
    return 0;
}
```

Also on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/1sIDjG).

Compiling some code similar to the above, I got no warning or whatsoever from Microsoft Visual C++ 2015, but a warning from GCC 5.4.0:

"warning: '0' flag used with '%p' gnu_printf format [-Wformat]"

Reading from [cppreference printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf), I see that:

> 0 : for integer and floating point number conversions, leading zeros
>   are used to pad the field instead of space characters. For integer
>   numbers it is ignored if the precision is explicitly specified. For
>   other conversions using this flag results in undefined behavior. It is
>   ignored if - flag is present.

As far as I can interpret, %p is for pointer address, which is an integer number after all, so does this undefined behavior apply to %p?
If not, why the GCC -Wformat warning?

Comment: I would guess because the code is nonsense that won't compile for fundamental syntax reasons? `printf("Pointer address: %08p", 
return 0;` Don't type code here, instead copy/paste the actual code or a working example.

Comment: Jez, right, I just discovered that copy&paste from Ideone does not work as I expected, edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `%p` is for pointer address, which is an integer number after all

Although pointers do have numeric representation, the standard does not consider pointers an integral data type. Therefore, using `%08p` format causes undefined behavior.

You can work around this problem by [using `uintptr_t` data type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1845482/335858), converting your pointer to it, and then printing it as an unsigned integer:

```
#include <cinttypes>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    int i = 123;
    void* p = &i;
    printf("%08" PRIxPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)p);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/dndD0j)

Answer (score 4):

> %p is for pointer address, which is an integer number after all,

Nope, a pointer is not an integer from the C/C++ type system point of view.

Pointers are neither arithmetic nor integral types, to be pedantic, see [std::is_integral](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral), [std::is_arithmetic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic).