# Strange error with preprocessor

Tags: c++, c

Currently I am having a very strange error with the preprocessor. I have searched and couldn't find anything relavent and therefore would like to post it here.
Below is my sample code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DDR_BASEADDR  0x000000000U + 128*1024*1024

int main()
{
     uint32_t* test2 = (uint32_t*) DDR_BASEADDR;

     uint32_t whatIsThis = DDR_BASEADDR;

     uint32_t* test3 = (uint32_t*) whatIsThis;

     printf( "%x %x %x %x\n\r", DDR_BASEADDR, test2, test3, whatIsThis);

     return 0;
}
```

The output of this code should all be `0x8000000`.
However, the outputs are:`8000000 20000000 8000000 8000000`.

I believe it is not the datatype that caused this problem, since it also appears even if i change `uint32_t* test2 = (uint32_t*) DDR_BASEADDR;` to `int32_t* test2 = (int32_t*) DDR_BASEADDR;`

I test this both on ARM A9 from the Zedboard and with [C++ online compiler](http://cpp.sh/) and get the same result.
Thank you for your time and effort.

Thang Tran

Comment: Braces are your friend `()`.

Comment: Hi Yunnosch, thank you for your answer. I tried it just now and you're right. Do you have any idea the reason behind this?

Comment: Still thinking, it was more of a gut feeling, triggered by seeing an operation in a macro, without braces.

Comment: To print a pointer using `printf` you should use the `"%p"` format, and its argument must be a `void *`. Mismatching formats and arguments leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Yunnosch : That confused me for a moment - `{...}` are "braces", `(...)` are _parentheses_.

Comment: Don't use macros to define values in C++. Use const/consterpr.

Comment: @Clifford Thanks for pointing out (no sarcasm). Actually I was unsure. That is why I added a quote of what exactly I mean. :-)

Comment: this is C++ code, not C code.  Please remove the C tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The macro expansion gives you

```
uint32_t* test2 = (uint32_t*) 0x000000000U + 128*1024*1024;
```

when you probably expected

```
uint32_t* test2 = (uint32_t*) (0x000000000U + 128*1024*1024);
```

That's why it is recommended to use lots of parenthesis in macro definitions, or - even better - use a function.

Comment: He did not expect the behavior of parenthesized expression (it would be `0x2000000` in all four printouts). He wanted `0x8000000` in the case when there's no cast to pointer, which he cannot get without making `0x000000000U` a pointer inside the macro itself.

Comment: *or - even better - use a function.* You have a reason why a function is better than macro with parenthesis?

Comment: Do *you* have a reason why a macro is better than a function, @tilz0R? A function should be your default choice unless there is some reason you actually need a macro. (Note, though, that a *constant* would have worked here, too.)

Comment: @CodyGray But macro is faster?

Comment: No, macros are not faster. Compilers have known how to inline functions since…I don't know, at least 20 years. @tilz0R

Comment: That's correct, but don't tell me that inline function can be faster than this macro in his case? @CodyGray It can only be at the same performance, just not better in any case.

Comment: Neither is faster than the other. It isn't a speed issue. It is a "make it easy to write correct, bug-free code" issue.

Comment: You can end up with a proliferation of parentheses; but the recommendation is not a simple as "lots of parentheses". The entire expression needs  _one_ outer pair of parentheses, and for function like macros with arguments, each instance of an argument in the expression requires parentheses.  Anything else is dependent of the semantics of the expression itself regardless of it being a macro or not.

Answer (score 4):

Your macro was expandend to:

```
uint32_t* test2 = (uint32_t*) 0x000000000U + 128*1024*1024;
```

Which is the same as doing this:

```
//Check multiply by sizeof at the end
uint32_t* test2 = (uint32_t *) (0x000000000U + 128*1024*1024 * sizeof(*test2));
```

because your size of the pointer type is `sizeof(uint32_t)` and therefore any operation for increase/decrease multiplies by this size.

What you want is:

```
uint32_t* test2 = (uint32_t *) (0x000000000U + 128*1024*1024);
```

Which means you first do calculation of address, then you cast to the desired pointer.

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely nothing strange about this: on this line

```
uint32_t* test2 = (uint32_t*) DDR_BASEADDR;
```

the cast to pointer operation is applied to `0x000000000U`, after which an `int` of `128*1024*1024` is added to the result of the cast, i.e.

```
uint32_t* test2 = (uint32_t*) 0x000000000U + 128*1024*1024;
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                       Pointer                Offset
```

This means the pointer arithmetic is performed, so in integer terms the offset value is multiplied by `sizeof(uint32_t)`, yielding `0x8000000`.

However, on this line

```
uint32_t whatIsThis = DDR_BASEADDR;
```

there is no cast to pointer, so the addition is done entirely in integers. That is why there is no multiplication by `sizeof(uint32_t)`, and the result is `0x20000000`.

If you want all four cases printing `800000000`, cast to pointer needs to be inside the macro:

```
#define DDR_BASEADDR  ((uint32_t*)0x000000000U + 128*1024*1024)
```

and a cast to `int32_t` needs to be on the declaration of `whatIsThis`:

```
uint32_t whatIsThis = (uint32_t)DDR_BASEADDR;
```

However, `uint32_t` is not a portable type for the pointer. Use [`uintptr_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1845482/335858) instead.

Comment: *However, uint32_t is not a portable type for the pointer. Use uintptr_t instead.* It is defined in C++11 and later.

Comment: The *type* `uint32_t` is defined in C++11 and later, but it isn't defined as being the same size as a pointer, @tilz0R. On lots of systems, pointers are 64 bits, and you will truncate them if you store them in a `uint32_t`.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree just tried to point out that it is not C89.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
#define DDR_BASEADDR  0x000000000U + 128*1024*1024
```

the code line

```
uint32_t* test2 = (uint32_t*) DDR_BASEADDR;
```

expands to

```
uint32_t* test2 = (uint32_t*) 0x000000000U + 128*1024*1024;
```

which is (because of the ways of pointer arithmetic) practically

```
uint32_t* test2 = (uint32_t*) (0x000000000U + (sizeof(uint32_t) *(128*1024*1024));
```

or

```
uint32_t* test2 = (uint32_t*) (0x000000000U + (4 * 0x8000000));
```

That gives you **200**00000 instead of **80**00000, both in hex format of course.
Multiplying by 4 in hex, for multiples of 4, is like multiplying by 16 (which in hex is like multiplying by 10 in decimal) and dividing by 4.
I.e.  it results in 1/4 the value, shifted left by one hex-digit: 80->200.

The other code lines have the effect of a pair of braces `()` in some way or another.

If you use

```
    #define DDR_BASEADDR  (0x000000000U + 128*1024*1024)
```

you should be fine, and are, as you have already verified.

Using braces generously is very good practice, especially with macros.

Note: You also should be more careful with printf and using the correct representation of the values you want to print (see comments and other answers). Otherwise the resulting **U**ndefined **B**ehaviour is evil! All kinds of unwanted and inexplicable things can result from UB.
However UB is not needed for explaining the values you get in this special case. (You got lucky.)