# Does uintptr_t store the address of a pointer or its value?

Tags: c++

Let us say I have the following code:

```
Foo *foo = something();
uintptr_t bar = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(foo);
```

Does `bar` represent the address of `foo` or the address that `foo` points to? I believe it's the address of `foo`, but I want to be certain that I am not mistaken.

**Some clarification**

[What is uintptr_t data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845482/what-is-uintptr-t-data-type) explains that

> In C99, it is defined as "an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer".

But this doesn't state *what* is being stored. Could the compiler conceivably store the address that `foo` points to in `bar` instead and then construct a new pointer with a different address when casting back to `Foo` from `uintptr_t`? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding pointer comparisons, but since they point to the same object, will they not compare equal?

I guess I'm looking for some pedantic clarity about about if I add the following line:

```
Foo *foo2 = reinterpret_cast<Foo *>(bar);
```

What on earth happens here? Undefined behavior? `foo2` just points to the same object as `foo`?

Comment: The address of `foo` is `&foo`, and that's a `Foo**` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an integral value that represents the address that `foo` points to.

If you were to write it as

```
uintptr_t bar = (uintptr_t)(&foo);
```

Then it would be the address of `foo` itself.

Comment: Ahhh. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what the cast is applied to.

In `uintptr_t bar = (uintptr_t)foo;` it stores the value of `foo` (the address of pointed to object) in `bar`.

Prefer using C++ casts, they convey more information to the reader and are more robust during maintenance - the best practice:

```
uintptr_t bar = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(foo);
```

Comment: I used C-style cast for brevity. My actual code uses `reinterpret_cast`. I will correct in the question.

Comment: Can you clarify on how it depends on the cast used, simply out of idle curiosity?

Comment: @JonHarper E.g. `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(foo)` and `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&foo)` are different cast expressions.