# Char Array and uintptr_t

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I was reading [What is uintptr_t data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845482/what-is-uintptr-t-data-type) but still I'm unable to understand `uintptr_t` here as

- what purpose it serve by first converting temporarily **char array** type to `unsigned long int` type and then converting back to `char*` type.

Consider the below code snapshot

```
strncpy(pCfgMgr->mGlobalCfg.grMap[index].userName,
       (char *)(uintptr_t) grParams.peerUsrName, 16); /*index is 0 */
```

where `userName` in the `pCfgMgr->mGlobalCfg.grMap[index].userName` is nothing but a char array declared as

```
char userName[MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH]; /* MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH is 16 */
```

And `peerUsrName` in the `grParams.peerUsrName` is also a char array declared as

```
char peerUsrName[16];
```

The thing which I didn't got is that *what `uintptr_t` makes the difference while copying, which is nothing but alias name of `unsigned long int`*. I am curious to know *what the developer was thinking while using `uintptr_t` here* & *is it recommended* ?

Though without `uintptr_t` above `strncpy()` statement produces the same output.

All helps appreciated wholeheartedly.

Comment: Using `(uintptr_t)` creates a dependency on the existence of `uintptr_t`, an optional type.  Code does not compile unless the common type `uintptr_t` exist.  More likely unnecessary than useful to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast is unnecessary.

The second argument to `strncpy` has type `const char *`.  An expression of type `char *` is also valid here.  `grParams.peerUsrName` has type `char [16]`.  Arrays in most contexts decay to a pointer to the first element.  So when you pass it to `strncpy` it decays to type `char *`, which is what it's expecting.  So no need for the cast.

Comment: Thanks. I agree about decaying part. I was in assumption that if user name length is just `16` or it may be hardly >100, not more in my case, why cast as `uinitptr_t`.

Comment: Any reason why dev could have gone for typecasting it to `uintptr_t`, like to avoid memory corruption ? I don't find have any clue about why `uintptr_t` needed here.

Comment: @Achal Maybe whoever wrote that code wasn't aware of the pointer decay rules.

Comment: Yes that may be the case.