# Which numerical types can be safely casted to intptr_t?

Tags: c, pointers, integer-overflow

`uintptr_t` and `intptr_t` are numerical types big enough to contain pointers, my question is how do they relate to other numerical types when casting toward them. Specifically which types (`int`, `long`, `long long`, `short`, `char`, `size_t` etc.) cant `NUM_TYPE` be defined as so that the next function does not corrupt the value of `n`?

```
intptr_t cast_num(NUM_TYPE n){return (intptr_t) n;}
```

Comment: This answer the question rather well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1846648/362589

Comment: Detail: `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t `are numerical types big enough to contain _object_ pointers - via a `void*`.  Function pointers may be too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optional types:

`intptr_t` has a range of *at least* [-0x7FFF...0x7FFF].

`uintptr_t` has a range of  [0... *at least* 0xFFFF].

---

Use `INTPTR_MIN, INTPTR_MAX, UINTPTR_MAX` from `<stdint.h>` to form condition code as needed.

```
intptr_t cast_long(unsigned long n) {
  _Static_assert(UIINTPTR_MAX >= ULONG_MAX, "unsigned long too big"): 
  return (intptr_t) n;
}
```

---

Note: Object pointers to/from `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t` should be converted through `void *`.  Function pointers may be too big.