# Resizing Heap Memory

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc, realloc

So I am trying to make a very simple wrapper around `malloc()` and `realloc()` for a lazy solution to a garbage collector. Problem is designing the garbage collector buffer. I want to store a pointer to pointers.

So I would need to initially allocate so arbitrary size of memory at initialisation. The problem is within this function I think. I want this function to be able to resize the buffer if it detected that the buffer is full. But currently, it is only happy if I either have a big buffer so I would not need to use this function.

```c
typedef struct ALLOC_STRUCT {
    void *cur_ptr;
    int index;
} alloc_T;

typedef struct GC_STRUCT {
    alloc_T **buffer; // Pointer that points to array of alloc_T pointers.
    int count; // Size of the buffer.
} gc_T;

void gc_resize(gc_T *gc) {
    if (gc->count == 4 && gc->count != 0) {
        gc_T *new_gc = realloc(gc, (sizeof *new_gc) + sizeof(uintptr_t) * (gc->count + ALLOCATION));
        if (new_gc) {
            gc = new_gc;
            gc->buffer = realloc(gc->buffer, sizeof(uintptr_t) * (gc->count + ALLOCATION));
            gc->count = gc->count;
        } else {
            // Error handling
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering if this problem could be either too much `realloc()` calls (which I do not think that to be the case) or my implementation of the garbage collector is wrong. Can anyone find any problems?

Here is the source code if anyone is really interested:
https://github.com/Zernoxi/New_Programming_Language/tree/memory_experiment/src

Comment: `if (gc->count == 4 && gc->count != 0) {` hmm... this seems wrong...

Comment: `gc_T *new_gc = realloc(gc, (sizeof *new_gc) + sizeof(uintptr_t) ....` makes no sense. The type `gc_T` is a fixed size type so assigning extra memory is meaningless.

Comment: Further it's unclear where `sizeof(uintptr_t)` comes from... to me it makes no sense.

Comment: `gc->count = gc->count;` won't do anything...

Comment: Changing `gc` inside the function won't change the `gc` used to call the function : either you have to `return gc` or have to pass a pointer  `gc_T **gc` to the function.

Comment: @JoëlHecht I'm omitting a lot of things but could I have modify `gc` passed into by the argument and that would change globally?

Comment: @4386427 I was just doing some tests. The program doesn't seem to complain about memory leaks if I set it to 4. `uinptr_t` is the size of a pointer.

Comment: @Zernoxi Memory leaks has nothing to do with wrong allocation. It's different things. And `uintptr_t` is not the size of a pointer.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/1846648/4386427

Comment: @4386427  Oh, so I should use `void *`?

Comment: `void *` would be better... but as stated above the whole `realloc` makes no sense so ...

Comment: @4386427 In the source code, `gc` is already initialised with `malloc`. What I want to do is increase `**buffer` to be able to fit more pointers.

Comment: `gc->buffer = realloc...` makes sense. But `gc_T *new_gc = realloc...` doesn't. Why would want to do that?

Comment: And notice: For `gcc->buffer` you don't use a temp variable... you should

Comment: Before I increase memory allocation for `gc->buffer`, wouldn't I also need to increase the memory allocation for `gc` to be able to hold a bigger `gc->buffer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JoëlHecht and @4386427 for the help. It seems that I have misinterpreted with how double pointers work.

```c
void gc_resize(gc_T *gc) {
    if (gc->count % 13 == 0 && gc->count != 0) {
        new_buffer = realloc(gc->buffer, sizeof(void *) * (gc->collect + 14));
        if (new_buffer == NULL) {
            // Error handling
        }
        gc->buffer = new_buffer;
    }
}
```