# Difference Between (uintptr_t) and (uint8_t *) in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, type-conversion

Is there any difference between (uintptr_t) and (uint8_t *)? Which is more portable?

Based on usage, can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: The former is integer type, the latter is a pointer type... Both are fully portable, in a sense that they are both standard.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The former is of unknown type.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Well, yeah. Assuming a typo over `uintptr_t`.

Comment: There is no standard-library type `uintptr`. There is `uintptr_t` in `stdint.h`. If that is what you mean, say so.

Comment: or [What is uintptr_t data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845482/what-is-uintptr-t-data-type) (C++)

Answer (score 2):

`uintptr_t` is an unsigned integer large enough to contain a `void *`, to which any pointer but a function pointer can be converted.

`uint8_t *` is a pointer to a `uint8_t`.

You ask if there are any differences, but I'm having problems coming up with any meaningful similarities. There just about as different as night and calendar.

Comment: Can you replace uintptr_t with (uint8_t *) without any consequences?

Comment: @Aison No you cannot

Comment: @Aison The answer is clearly stating that these types are not interchangeable. Like "night and calendar"."

Comment: Any reasons? It seems to me that you can perform arithmetic operations on them and both have the same outputs.

Comment: @Aison `uint8_t *a = ..., *b = ...;` now try `a + b;` - the same with two `uintptr_t`'s will of course work fine, since it's just a normal unsigned integer.

Comment: Ah I see. Besides arithmetic operations, any cases that we use uintptr_t instead of (void *)

Comment: "uintptr_t is an unsigned integer large enough to contain a pointer." -->more like "uintptr_t is an unsigned integer large enough to contain a `void *` pointer." which covers most pointers aside from function pointers.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica, So that means `int *p; (uintptr_t)p` should be `int *p; (uintptr_t)(void *)p`? Updated.

Comment: Re "*It seems to me that you can perform arithmetic operations on them*", Not really, no. It's meaningless to perform arithmetic on a `uintptr_t`, and there are very strict limits on what arithmetic operations can be taken on a pointer. For example, `uint8_t b = 3; uint8_t *p = &b; p = p + 1;` is valid, but `uint8_t b = 3; uint8_t *p = &b; p = p + 2;` isn't.

Comment: @ikegami "Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined."  (C17 6.3.2.3 Pointers).  Going through `void*` to and from is well defined to form equivalent pointers.  Without `void*`, the spec is fuzzier on the equivalent part.  Rarely an issue to skip `void*` unless `void*, int *` have different encodings/sizes.  Something uncommon in 2022.

Answer (score 0):

I would say `{signed,unsigned,} char*` as neither `uint8_t` nor `uintptr_t` are guaranteed to be defined, strictly speaking.

`char_type *` is not interchangeable with `uintptr_t`, however.
While you can use `char_type *` to point at the bytes of an object, you can do *wilder* pointer arithmetic with `uintptr_t` because then you don't necessarily get undefined behavior cases if you end up pointing at a wrong place.

E.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(){
    char a[]={11,22,33};
    //for(char *p=a+2; p!=a-1;--p)
    //  printf("%d\n", *p); //undefined reverse iteration: can't point to &a[-1]
    for(uintptr_t p=(uintptr_t)(a+2); p!=(uintptr_t)a-1;--p) 
        printf("%d\n", *(char*)p); //OK; (uintptr_t)&a[0] - 1 is just a number
}
```