Can I cast an unsigned long int into uintptr_t without losing bits?
uintptr_t uint_to_uintptr(unsigned int n) {
    return (uintptr_t)n;
}

uintptr_t ulint_to_uintptr(unsigned long int n) {
    return (uintptr_t)n;
}

uintptr_t ullint_to_uintptr(unsigned long long int n) {
    return (uintptr_t)n;
}

Which of the 3 casts above does not cause a loss of information (bits)?
The c99 standard says:

The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
uintptr_t


but it does not specify what the size of this unsigned integer type is.
Does it mean the maximum value of greatest-width unsigned integer type (UINTMAX_MAX) or a simple unsigned int?

If there were a standard integer type known to be large enough, you wouldn't need this type. Why do you need to do this?

@Barmar Not sure I understand what you meant, do you mean I can convert an unsinged long long int to uintptr_t without losing bits?

The implementation may have 64-bit long long but only 32 bit pointers. Such as the older 32-bit MS VC, where sizeof(uintptr_t) is 4. So no, you can't necessarily do that.

I misread the question, I thought you were asking about converting from uintptr_t to one of the unsigned int types. But it's undefined in both directions.

The only thing that's well-defined is converting back and forth between uintptr_t and void*. Why would you need to convert a regular unsigned int to uintptr_t?

@WeatherVane so what is the size of this unsigned integer type (which the c99 standard refers to) that can be converted to uintptr_t?

@Barmar If what you say is true, then what is the point of having the uintptr_t type? Why did the c99 standard create this type?

The unsigned integer type is uintptr_t that your quote mentions. You missed the fact that it is a pointer that is converted to this type.

afaik, none of your 3 casts the standard guarantees no loss of information. As the standard says, the only type it guarantees lossless conversion from is uintptr_t.

The point of it is to have a portable integer type that can hold a pointer. In 32-bit systems it's usually unsigned int, in 64-bit systems it's unsigned long.

@Barmar or unsigned long long, the unsigned long usually being a poor choice (its best place is when int is 16 bits).

What if uintptr_t doesn't exist?  It's an optional type.

@Barmar Sorry (I'm probably a little slow on the uptake), could you please give me a practical example where it is better to use a uintptr_t instead of a void *?

You don't use it instead of void*. You use it instead of unsigned long long when you need to convert the pointer to an integer for some reason.

Are you asking why you would need to convert a pointer to an integer in the first place? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845482/what-is-the-uintptr-t-data-type

I have used uintptr_t when I want to align memory to a 32k byte boundary to prevent cache breaks. I allocated twice that, and aligned a different pointer to use.

@Barmar thanks, now I understand, none of the 3 casts above guarantee no bit loss, because the uintptr_t type is not intended to contain any kind of unsigned int type, but only pointers on which is possible to perform integer-specific operations such as shift, XOR, OR, AND, etc...
Quite fascinating, I had never thought of that

@Parminder Singh, you make enjoy Detecting unicorn and dinosaur compilers.

About the widths1 and representation capabilities of these types and the relations between them, the C 2018 standard specifies each type can represent at least the value shown here:



Type
Value
Source in Standard




unsigned int
65,535
5.2.4.2.1 1


unsigned long int
4,294,967,295
5.2.4.2.1 1


unsigned long long int
18,446,744,073,709,551,615
5.2.4.2.1 1


uintptr_t
65,535
7.20.2.4 1



and it specifies these additional requirements:

unsigned long int is at least as wide as unsigned int (6.3.1.1 1, as a consequence of rank properties).

unsigned long long int is at least as wide as unsigned int and unsigned long long int (6.3.1.1 1, as a consequence of rank properties).

uintptr_t can, in some fashion, represent any valid void * (7.20.1.4 1).


As we can see from these, there is no limit on how big any of the types unsigned int, unsigned long int, or unsigned long long int can be, and no rule prevents any of them from being wider or narrower than uintptr_t. Therefore, there is no guarantee in the C standard that converting an unsigned int, unsigned long int, or unsigned long long int to uintptr_t will not lose information.
Footnote
1 The width of an integer type is the number of bits used to represent its value, including a sign bit if any. The precision is the number of bits used to represent its value excluding any sign bit. For an unsigned type, the width and the precision are the same.

Thanks for the reply, but my question was the opposite, can I convert an unsigned integer to uintptr_t without losing bits? instead you answered the question: can I convert a uintptr_t to an unsigned integer without losing bits?

@ParminderSingh: Fixed. The conclusion is the same; the C standard does not impose any relation between the widths of uintptr_t and the other unsigned integer types, so the conversion in either direction may lose information.

A while back I did a survey of all semi-recent platforms that I could find a compiler for. There were only 6 "models" of integer/pointer sizes (only pointer, int, and long vary between them; sizeof(size_t) always matches sizeof(uintptr_t) [edit: except on DOS's "large" model, possibly medium and compact also]; note that not all pointer bits might actually get used, and when there are multiple integers of a given width, different typedefs might be to different-ranked ones):

SP16. Pointers are 16 bits; int and long are 32 bits. This one will fail, but it's pretty rare (at least as a default configuration, though the alternate is usually the next one which fails too).
IP16. Pointers and ints are 16 bits; long is 32 bits. This one will also fail, and is much more common.
LP32. Pointers and longs are 32 bits; ints are only 16 bits. This includes 16-bit x86 (e.g. MS-DOS) when using far pointers exclusively.
ILP32. Pointers, ints, and longs are all 32 bits. This was by far the most common kind of platform prior to the last few years.
LP64. Int is 32 bits; long and pointer are 64 bits. This is by far the most common kind of platform today.
LLP64. Int and long are 32 bits; pointer is 64 bits. This is only used on Windows.


Being pedantic: I observe the DOS version of LP32 has sizeof(size_t) = 2.

Oh, right. I didn't actually get a compiler for that one, so I didn't store it in the same place. From re-reading documentation, you're correct for the "large" model, but not for the "huge" model (which allows >64KB arrays).

And almost nobody used huge model because pointer arithmetic was too slow. Instead you declared the handful of individual pointers huge and called hmalloc to allocate a big array.

"LP64. Int is 32 bits; long and pointer are 64 bits. This is by far the most common kind of platform today." --> given that far and away embedded platforms are the most common (IIRC, billions per year), I doubt that the largest share of these is a 64-bit address scheme.


Can I cast an unsigned long int into uintptr_t?


[OP changed things]
Can I cast an unsigned long int into uintptr_t without losing bits?

The only unsigned type guaranteed to not lose info would be from unsigned char to uintptr_t.


Code can always convert an unsigned type into another unsigned type.  The cast quiets a warning that may otherwise occur.

Info may be loss if the destination type is a sub-range.


This is just fine.
uintptr_t ullint_to_uintptr(unsigned long long int n) {
    return (uintptr_t)n;
}


Yet was the cast needed?  Maybe not.  Code can use an #if to determine.
uintptr_t ullint_to_uintptr(unsigned long long int n) {
    // C allows this to be true as pointer size, and hence `intptr_t` is not in a tight relationship with `unsigned long long`.
    #if UINTPTR_MAX < ULLONG_MAX
      return (uintptr_t) n;
    #else
      return n;
    #endif
}


I made a mistake by not specifying "without losing bits" in the title (I just edited it), anyway the answer seems to be that none of the 3 casts above guarantee no bit loss.

@ParminderSingh What is your case where you need to do this?

The #if is not needed (the same code is generated with or without it), return n; here does a cast to  uintptr_t.

@pts The cast remains useful when UINTPTR_MAX < ULLONG_MAX and many warnings are enabled (like -Wconversion, etc.) as this quiets the warning since return n; loses info.

@chux-ReinstateMonica I don't need to do this conversion, I was just curious about this guy I met while reading the c99 standard.

The #if is not needed: return (uintptr_t)n; works and silences warnings unconditionally.

@pts True, yet this answer addresses if the cast is needed.  Yes it is trading off a potential cast for an #if.  In general, cast should be avoided.  Of course conditional compiled code should like-wise be avoided.  In this trivial code, it makes sense to leave the cast in, yet with a more complex version, the #if makes sense.

Most C compilers (with optimizations enabled) generate the same machine code with or without the cast. There is no need for the #if here. (Some C compilers, with optimizations disabled, generate equivalent but slower machine code because of the cast.)

I'm not sure that the C standard guarantees that a conversion from unsigned char to uintptr_t will be done without loss of information. The minimum width of an unsigned char is guaranteed to be 8 bits, which means it can also be 32 bits and a uintptr_t can be 16 bits, although in the real world I don't think such strange architectures exist.

@ParminderSingh I'm not sure that the C standard guarantees that a conversion from unsigned char to uintptr_t will be done without loss of information.  Yes, it does, because uintptr_t is defined as "an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type...".  And every unsigned integer type available must be at least as large as unsigned char.  It's not explicitly guaranteed, but it must be true given the ranks of unsigned integer types.

@AndrewHenle I hadn't thought of that, it's not explicitly stated, but implicitly it seems to be guaranteed, good point!
