# Disable "warning: the address of 'x' will always evaluate as 'true'"

Tags: c, gcc, macros, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

The problem is this:

```
#define do_stuff(ret) ((ret) ? getstuff(ret) : 0)
int var;
do_stuff(&var);

test.h:34:46: warning: the address of 'var' will always evaluate as 'true' [-Waddress]
```

`do_stuff` acts as a function that accepts an output-pointer that can be NULL, though, thus the warning is not helpful but annoying.
Is there a way via code to make gcc stop complaining? Maybe an (at least kind of) portable one?

Btw. `do_stuff` has to be a macro as `ret` actually gets set in a generic way (here stripped for simplicity).

**Edit**:
Again, I just want to have the usual output-pointer that can be NULL, but inside a macro instead of a function. The actual code looks like this:

```
#define retrieve(x, ret) \
    ( ret ? (*ret = x.buf[0], 1) : 0 )
```

which gave the warning from above when using it like `retrieve(stuff, NULL)`. Accordingly to *Adriano Repetti*'s answer, I changed it to:

```
#define retrieve(x, ret) \
    ( ((void *)ret != NULL) ? (*ret = x.buf[0], 1) : 0 )
```

which works, but now gives me `warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer` as this gets expanded to `( ((void *)NULL != NULL) ? (*NULL = x.buf[0], 1) : 0 )`. Is there a way I can get rid of this warning, too?

`retrieve` **has** to be a macro because x.buf is of variant type, and so is `ret`, passing it through a function like in *2501*'s tip would result in type loss.

Comment: What do you mean "`ret` actually gets set in a generic way"?  Is it always an `int*`?  If not can you use a `void*` in the function prototype?

Comment: Like in "only macros are capable of doing that"-generic, if I used a `void *`, I would need to `memcpy`, which slows down the code.

Comment: the contents of var might possibly be 0/NULL however the address of a variable, especially on the stack, will always be some non-zero value.  so the compiler is correct.  perhaps what you really want is to pass the contents (pass by value) of the var variable.  if so, then remove the '&' from the invocation of the macro

Comment: @netcat about your last edit: you may introduce a dummy local variable: *((void*)ret != NULL) ? &dummy : ret) = x.buf[0], 1

Comment: Nice idea. `((*(((void *)(ret) != NULL) ? (ret) : &dummy)) = x.buf[0], 1)` works with _NULL_ and _&var_. However, the downside of this is 1. that with _ret = NULL_ there is a dummy assignment emitted and 2. in this particular example you couldn't return 0 when there is no pointer supplied. I was hoping the compiler wouldn't validate the `*NULL = x.buf[0]` since `(NULL != NULL) ?` will never be the case..

Comment: @Adriano Repetti: Oops, sorry. I could've just combined both of your answers to `((void *)(ret) != NULL) ? ((*(((void *)(ret) != NULL) ? (ret) : &dummy)) = x.buf[0], 1) : 0`. It's kind of ugly and redundant, but it works. Again, smart thinking of yours.

Comment: @netcat yes it looks pretty weird also to me, good candidate for a long comment or hmmmm some nested macros or hmmmm I don't know...here I miss C++ templates

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you really can't avoid a macro and considering that I wouldn't disable warnings (even if this particular one isn't *dangerous*) then I'd *cheat* compiler with some casts. Code will be portable and no warnings will be emitted:

```
#define do_stuff(ret) (((uintptr_t)NULL != (uintptr_t)ret) ? getstuff(ret) : 0)
```

Central point here is simply this: `(uintptr_t)NULL != (uintptr_t)ret`. I'd suggest to also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153065/converting-a-pointer-into-an-integer) here on SO. Note that also simply `NULL != (void*)ret` works.

Comment: @2501 I don't know...I hope he/she will explain!

Comment: What compiler are you using? This appears to be compiler dependant, mine retains the warning for `!= NULL`, but no warning for `(uintptr_t)NULL !=`, and no warning for my approach.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. I kind of thought that casting might hinder the compiler from emitting warnings. I didn't test it though. Thanks

Comment: @2501 gcc 4.8.1, I like your approach too: it introduces a fake function but it'll be optimized away (in general and especially with macros, casting may hide terrible bugs)

Comment: I can now answer my own comment, as to why this is downvoted. Unlike pointer comparison, comparisons using pointers which are cast to uintptr_t, is not defined in C.

Comment: @2501 why? You can always cast to/from void* and it's a normal integer type (where comparison is safest thing you can imagine to do). Why it's UB?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Because C Standard doesn't define it. Two pointers to the same object may have different bit representation.

Comment: @2501 I admit I can't understand what you mean. C standards define conversions to/from uintptr_t. C standards define operations between uintptr_t. That's all we need to know, we're not _manipulating_ uintptr_t before converting back to T*. In this case we don't even need to worry about normalization. In short: can we convert any pointer to uintptr_t and compare it with something? Yes, perfectly allowed (and defined because we're using uintptr_t not an arbitrary integer type).

Comment: Two pointers to the same object may have different bit representation. The comparison `==` of those two pointers will nevertheless yield true. Alas when those two pointers are converted to uintptr_t, comparisons `==` of those two integers may not yield true. This didn't happen on the architecture you're using, but C allows such an architecture, which means that this code will not work correctly on such an architecture.

Comment: I understand that, however here we do not rely on what you're mentioning. We convert to uintptr_t and compare with 0 (which is a well-defined value in C). There isn't any other assumption.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a dummy function that just returns the pointer, this might silence the compiler:

```
void* pass( void* a )
{
    return a ;
}

#define do_stuff(ret) ( pass(ret) ? getstuff(ret) : 0)
int var;
do_stuff( &var );
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as well. However, casting adds less clutter.

Answer (score 2):

GCC's -Waddress command line flag is used to disable this type of warnings. But it's better to write your code without warnings.