# What is the reverse operation of "myType& var = *(myType*) addrVar;" (c++)

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

In a code I didn't write and I have to use, using OpenCV (but it could be anything) I come across something like :

```
void foo (long addrImage){
[...]
   Mat& image  = *(Mat*)addrImage;
[...]
}
```

I want to do the reverse operation : create an adress based on a `Mat&`, but I'm not sure I understand completely the trick used.

What would the line be ?

Comment: Trick? Any reason `Mat* p = &image` doesn't work?

Comment: long addrImage = (long)&image

Comment: That's bad code anyways. Casting a `long` to a pointer is undefined behavior.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I thought it was implementation-defined?

Comment: @TartanLlama Hmmm, well implementation specific. Bad code though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Found the quote: [expr.reinterpret.cast]/6: A value of integral type or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to a pointer. A pointer converted
to an integer of sufficient size (if any such exists on the implementation) and back to the same pointer type
will have its original value; mappings between pointers and integers are otherwise implementation-defined.

Comment: If this is on some embedded platform with memory-mapped i/o, I don't think it's bad code. Otherwise, sure.

Comment: @ πάντα-ῥεῖ Well it's JNI for Android (so it's actually a jlong) and I can't change the whole project. I didn't chose to store adresses as longs...

Comment: @TeleportingGoat [UKMonkey gave you the correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994687/what-is-the-reverse-operation-of-mytype-var-mytype-addrvar-c#comment67267384_39994687)

Comment: For a little more reading on why long isn't really the type you want to use - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153065/converting-a-pointer-into-an-integer

Comment: Am I right to understand that `*(Mat*)addrImage` is a pointer to  `addrImage` converted to a `Mat*` ?

Comment: addrImage is `long` (number). It is then cast into `Mat*` pointer (which means the same number is used as address), and then it's dereferenced by `*` into the `Mat` instance itself. Of that one the reference `Mat &` is created in temporary local variable (for simple access of that `Mat` instance). @πάνταῥεῖ: Android + JNI libraries are full of this long<->ptr (and all other evil). I think the creators of JNI made it intentionally so, that everything good about C++ is lost on the interface level, to make it total hell to use (at least for me it's hell), so people will rather stick in pure Java.

Comment: @Ped7g I'm scared about running my phone and tablet now :P

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's just phone, what can go wrong... I just wonder why people voluntarily want it to connect to a car, "smart" home, or anything else which can mechanically kill you in case something goes wrong. It's like they have absolutely no idea how it works and what's inside. And then there's the "IoT". My favourite horror movie. (sorry for chat in SO comments, ending it here)

Comment: @UKMonkey I'd accept your solution if it was an answer. It seems to work. @ Ped7g Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

long addrImage = (long)&image